# Handling errors in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have an array of Promises that I'm resolving with `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);`

I go on to continue the promise chain. Looks something like this

```
existingPromiseChain = existingPromiseChain.then(function() {
  var arrayOfPromises = state.routes.map(function(route){
    return route.handler.promiseHandler();
  });
  return Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
});

existingPromiseChain = existingPromiseChain.then(function(arrayResolved) {
  // do stuff with my array of resolved promises, eventually ending with a res.send();
});
```

I want to add a catch statement to handle an individual promise in case it errors, but when I try, `Promise.all` returns the first error it finds (disregards the rest), and then I can't get the data from the rest of the promises in the array (that didn't error).

I've tried doing something like ..

```
existingPromiseChain = existingPromiseChain.then(function() {
      var arrayOfPromises = state.routes.map(function(route){
        return route.handler.promiseHandler()
          .then(function(data) {
             return data;
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
             return err
          });
      });
      return Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
    });

existingPromiseChain = existingPromiseChain.then(function(arrayResolved) {
      // do stuff with my array of resolved promises, eventually ending with a res.send();
});
```

But that doesn't resolve.

--

Edit:

What the answers below said were completely true, the code was breaking due to other reasons. In case anyone is interested, this is the solution I ended up with ...

Node Express Server Chain

```
serverSidePromiseChain
    .then(function(AppRouter) {
        var arrayOfPromises = state.routes.map(function(route) {
            return route.async();
        });
        Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
            .catch(function(err) {
                // log that I have an error, return the entire array;
                console.log('A promise failed to resolve', err);
                return arrayOfPromises;
            })
            .then(function(arrayOfPromises) {
                // full array of resolved promises;
            })
    };
```

---

API Call (route.async call)

```
return async()
    .then(function(result) {
        // dispatch a success
        return result;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // dispatch a failure and throw error
        throw err;
    });
```

Putting the `.catch` for `Promise.all` before the `.then` seems to have served the purpose of catching any errors from the original promises, but then returning the entire array to the next `.then`.

Comment: Your attempt seems like it should work… maybe there’s another problem somewhere later?

Comment: `.then(function(data) { return data; })` can be completely omitted

Comment: The only reason that the above should not resolve is if there you're not showing us all the code in the `then` or `catch` handlers and there's an error being thrown inside. By the way, is this node?

Comment: You have no final catch in your "existing chain", so there may be errors you're not seeing that might explain why it "doesn't resolve". Try adding that and see what error you get.

Comment: here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises/36115549#36115549

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/1048572)

Answer (score 295, accepted):

`Promise.all` is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as *one* of them rejects. In other words, it either resolves with an array of all resolved values, or rejects with a single error.

Some libraries have something called `Promise.when`, which I understand would instead wait for *all* promises in the array to either resolve or reject, but I'm not familiar with it, and it's not in ES6.

**Your code**

I agree with others here that your fix should work. It should resolve with an array that may contain a mix of successful values and errors objects. It's unusual to pass error objects in the success-path but assuming your code is expecting them, I see no problem with it.

The only reason I can think of why it would "not resolve" is that it's failing in code you're not showing us and the reason you're not seeing any error message about this is because this promise chain is not terminated with a final catch (as far as what you're showing us anyway).

I've taken the liberty of factoring out the "existing chain" from your example and terminating the chain with a catch. This may not be right for you, but for people reading this, it's important to always either return or terminate chains, or potential errors, even coding errors, will get hidden (which is what I suspect happened here):

```
Promise.all(state.routes.map(function(route) {
  return route.handler.promiseHandler().catch(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
}))
.then(function(arrayOfValuesOrErrors) {
  // handling of my array containing values and/or errors. 
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.message); // some coding error in handling happened
});
```

Comment: You (and the above comments) were right. My route.handler.promiseHandler needed to .catch() and return the error. I also needed to add the final .catch() to the end of the chain. Thanks for relaying the importance of having success / error handlers at every step of the chain :).

Comment: I found out also that if I throw the error in my .catch() for route.handler.promiseHandler, it will automatically go to the final catch. If I return the error instead, it will do what I want and handle the entire array.

Comment: There is now a standard method `Promise.allSettled()` with decent support. See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

Comment: Yes, `Promise.all` fails, when the first thread fails. But unfortunately all the other threads still continue to run until they finish. Nothing is cancelled, even worse: There is no way to cancel a thread in `Promise`. So whatever the threads are doing (and manipulating) they continue, they change states and variables, they use CPU, but at the end they don't return their result. You need to be aware of this to not produce a chaos, e.g. when you repeat / retry the call.

Comment: > But unfortunately all the other threads still continue to run until they finish. Nothing is cancelled, even worse ...

---
I'd argue that this is _good_ behavior. Interrupting all other promises when one fails would lead to undefined behavior and resource leaks.

Answer (score 251):

**NEW ANSWER**

```
const results = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(e => e)));
const validResults = results.filter(result => !(result instanceof Error));
```

**FUTURE Promise API**

- Chrome 76: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled
- You can download https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled to get it now. In certain browsers allSettled comes preinstalled with the browser itself. It's worth downloading the package for peace of mind because eg. TypeScript doesn't have default definitions for allSettled.

Comment: Though `e` does not have to be an `Error`. It may be a string, for example, if someone returns it like `Promise.reject('Service not available')`.

Comment: @ArturKlesun how could we then classify which of the promise resulted in error and which did not?

Comment: @shubham-jain with `.then()` and `.catch()`. `Promise.resolve()` would pass value to the former, whereas **`Promise.reject()`** will pass it to the latter. You can wrap them in object for example: `p.then(v => ({success: true, value: v})).catch(e => ({success: false, error: e}))`.

Comment: Why would you filter the results?  That makes no sense if you're doing anything with the results – you need the order to know which returned value is from which promise!

Answer (score 139):

**ES2020** introduces new method for the `Promise` type: `Promise.allSettled()`.

> `Promise.allSettled` gives you a signal when all the input promises are settled, which means they’re either fulfilled or rejected. This is useful in cases where you don’t care about the state of the promise, you just want to know when the work is done, regardless of whether it was successful.

```js
async function() {
  const promises = [
    fetch('/api.stackexchange.com/2.2'), // succeeds
    fetch('/this-will-fail') // fails
  ];

  const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  console.log(result.map(promise => promise.status));
  // ['fulfilled', 'rejected']
}
```

Read more in the [v8 blog post](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators).

Comment: does it also work in the firebase functions?

Comment: I used it with firebase functions couple years ago. You have to ensure that your NodeJS version from firebase is compatible with `allSettled`.

Answer (score 32):

## Promise.allSettled

Instead of Promise.all use [Promise.allSettled](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-allsettled) which waits for all promises to settle, regardless of the result

```js
let p1 = new Promise(resolve => resolve("result1"));
let p2 = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => reject('some troubles') );
let p3 = new Promise(resolve => resolve("result3"));

// It returns info about each promise status and value
Promise.allSettled([p1,p2,p3]).then(result=> console.log(result));
```

[Polyfill](https://javascript.info/promise-api#promise-allsettled)

```js
if (!Promise.allSettled) {
  const rejectHandler = reason => ({ status: 'rejected', reason });
  const resolveHandler = value => ({ status: 'fulfilled', value });

  Promise.allSettled = function (promises) {
    const convertedPromises = promises
      .map(p => Promise.resolve(p).then(resolveHandler, rejectHandler));
    return Promise.all(convertedPromises);
  };
}
```

Comment: note as described here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise that it does not support firefox for android

Comment: @adirabargil thanks for this info - [here is polyfill](https://javascript.info/promise-api#polyfill) for this

Comment: UPDATE: 12/12/2023 Firefox and Android added support.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Answer (score 26):

To continue the `Promise.all` loop (even when a Promise rejects) I wrote a utility function which is called `executeAllPromises`. This utility function returns an object with `results` and `errors`.

The idea is that all Promises you pass to `executeAllPromises` will be wrapped into a new Promise which will always resolve. The new Promise resolves with an array which has 2 spots. The first spot holds the resolving value (if any)  and the second spot keeps the error (if the wrapped Promise rejects).

As a final step the `executeAllPromises` accumulates all values of the wrapped promises and returns the final object with an array for `results` and an array for `errors`.

**Here is the code:**

```js
function executeAllPromises(promises) {
  // Wrap all Promises in a Promise that will always "resolve"
  var resolvingPromises = promises.map(function(promise) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var payload = new Array(2);
      promise.then(function(result) {
          payload[0] = result;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          payload[1] = error;
        })
        .then(function() {
          /* 
           * The wrapped Promise returns an array:
           * The first position in the array holds the result (if any)
           * The second position in the array holds the error (if any)
           */
          resolve(payload);
        });
    });
  });

  var errors = [];
  var results = [];

  // Execute all wrapped Promises
  return Promise.all(resolvingPromises)
    .then(function(items) {
      items.forEach(function(payload) {
        if (payload[1]) {
          errors.push(payload[1]);
        } else {
          results.push(payload[0]);
        }
      });

      return {
        errors: errors,
        results: results
      };
    });
}

var myPromises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.reject(new Error('3')),
  Promise.resolve(4),
  Promise.reject(new Error('5'))
];

executeAllPromises(myPromises).then(function(items) {
  // Result
  var errors = items.errors.map(function(error) {
    return error.message
  }).join(',');
  var results = items.results.join(',');
  
  console.log(`Executed all ${myPromises.length} Promises:`);
  console.log(`— ${items.results.length} Promises were successful: ${results}`);
  console.log(`— ${items.errors.length} Promises failed: ${errors}`);
});
```

Comment: This can be done simpler. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36115549/918910

Answer (score 19):

As @jib said,

> `Promise.all` is all or nothing.

Though, you can control certain promises that are "allowed" to fail and we would like to proceed to `.then`.

For example.

```
  Promise.all([
    doMustAsyncTask1,
    doMustAsyncTask2,
    doOptionalAsyncTask
    .catch(err => {
      if( /* err non-critical */) {
        return
      }
      // if critical then fail
      throw err
    })
  ])
  .then(([ mustRes1, mustRes2, optionalRes ]) => {
    // proceed to work with results
  })
```

Answer (score 8):

Using Async await -

here one async function func1 is returning a resolved value, and func2 is throwing a error and returning a null in this situation, we can handle it how we want and return accordingly.

```
const callingFunction  = async () => {
    const manyPromises = await Promise.all([func1(), func2()]);
    console.log(manyPromises);
}


const func1 = async () => {
    return 'func1'
}

const func2 = async () => {
    try {
        let x;
        if (!x) throw "x value not present"
    } catch(err) {
       return null
    }
}

callingFunction();
```

Output is - [ 'func1', null ]

Answer (score 6):

if you get to use the q library https://github.com/kriskowal/q
it has q.allSettled() method that can solve this problem
you can handle every promise depending on its state either fullfiled or rejected
so

```
existingPromiseChain = existingPromiseChain.then(function() {
var arrayOfPromises = state.routes.map(function(route){
  return route.handler.promiseHandler();
});
return q.allSettled(arrayOfPromises)
});

existingPromiseChain = existingPromiseChain.then(function(arrayResolved) {
//so here you have all your promises the fulfilled and the rejected ones
// you can check the state of each promise
arrayResolved.forEach(function(item){
   if(item.state === 'fulfilled'){ // 'rejected' for rejected promises
     //do somthing
   } else {
     // do something else
   }
})
// do stuff with my array of resolved promises, eventually ending with a res.send();
});
```

Comment: Since you are suggesting the use of some library (`q`), it would be more useful if you provided a usage example related to the question. As it stands, your answer does not explain how this library can help resolve the problem.

Comment: added an example as suggested

Comment: Circa 2018 one should always see what Sindre has available :-).  https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-settle.  With Sindre's single purpose modules you don't have to import a huge library like q  for just one bit.

Answer (score 5):

## Promise.allSettled with a filter

```
const promises = [
  fetch('/api-call-1'),
  fetch('/api-call-2'),
  fetch('/api-call-3'),
];
// Imagine some of these requests fail, and some succeed.

const resultFilter = (result, error) => result.filter(i => i.status === (!error ? 'fulfilled' : 'rejected')).map(i => (!error ? i.value : i.reason));

const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

const fulfilled = resultFilter(result); // all fulfilled results
const rejected = resultFilter(result, true); // all rejected results
```

Answer (score 4):

For those using ES8 that stumble here, you can do something like the following, using [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
var arrayOfPromises = state.routes.map(async function(route){
  try {
    return await route.handler.promiseHandler();
  } catch(e) {
    // Do something to handle the error.
    // Errored promises will return whatever you return here (undefined if you don't return anything).
  }
});

var resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can handle the rejection at the individual promises level, so when we get the results in our result array, the array index which has been rejected will be `undefined`. We can handle that situation as needed, and use the remaining results.

Here I have rejected the first promise, so it comes as undefined, but we can use the result of the second promise, which is at index 1.

```js
const manyPromises = Promise.all([func1(), func2()]).then(result => {
    console.log(result[0]);  // undefined
    console.log(result[1]);  // func2
});

function func1() {
    return new Promise( (res, rej) => rej('func1')).catch(err => {
        console.log('error handled', err);
    });
}

function func2() {
    return new Promise( (res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res('func2'), 500) );
}
```

Comment: How can you do a similar thing if we use async await?

Comment: I have answered your question, please find the link for the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55216763/4079716

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered `Promise.prototype.finally()`?

It seems to be designed to do exactly what you want - execute a function once all the promises have settled (resolved/rejected), regardless of some of the promises being rejected.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally):

The `finally()` method can be useful if you want to do some processing or cleanup once the promise is settled, regardless of its outcome.

The `finally()` method is very similar to calling `.then(onFinally, onFinally)` however there are couple of differences:

When creating a function inline, you can pass it once, instead of being forced to either declare it twice, or create a variable for it.

A finally callback will not receive any argument, since there's no reliable means of determining if the promise was fulfilled or rejected. This use case is for precisely when you do not care about the rejection reason, or the fulfillment value, and so there's no need to provide it.

Unlike `Promise.resolve(2).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be resolved with undefined), `Promise.resolve(2).finally(() => {})` will be resolved with 2.
Similarly, unlike `Promise.reject(3).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be fulfilled with undefined), `Promise.reject(3).finally(() => {})` will be rejected with 3.

== Fallback ==

If your version of JavaScript doesn't support `Promise.prototype.finally()` you can use this workaround from [Jake Archibald](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/833668073475416064): `Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => undefined)));`

Comment: Yes, until `Promises.allSettled()` is actually implemented (it's documented by MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)), then `Promises.all.finally()` would seem to accomplish the same thing.  I am about to give it a try...

Comment: @jamess Why don't you make this comment as a proper answer ? None of the answers refer to ES6 `allSettled()`.

Comment: @pravin - From what I can tell, `allSettled()` is not implemented anywhere (yet), so I don't want to get ahead of reality.  I had success with `Promises.all(myPromiseArray).finally()`, and that fits with this answer.  Once `allSettled()` actually exists, then I might test it and find out how it actually works.  Until then, who knows what the browsers will actually implement?  Unless you have recent info to the contrary...

Comment: @jamess True that its still in draft stage.. however latest FF and chrome seem to support it fully.. Not sure of it stability tho..[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)
Anyways the point I was trying to make was that it would have much easier to find if it was an answer than a comment.. it ur call though :)

Comment: @pravin - At the time I posted my comment, it was not implemented anywhere. I just tested in Firefox and Chrome: `Promise.allSettled` is not implemented in Firefox, but it does appear to exist in Chrome.  Just because docs say it's implemented doesn't mean that it really is implemented.  I'm not going to use it anytime soon.

Comment: @jamess Cool.. anyways.. the comment helped me.. thank you for that

Answer (score 3):

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'foo'));
const promises = [promise1, promise2];
let sum = 0;
let promiseErrorArr = [];

Promise.allSettled(promises)
.then((results) => {
          results.forEach(result => {
            if (result.status === "rejected") {
              sum += 1;
              promiseErrorArr.push(result)
            }
          })
    return ( (sum>0) ? promiseFailed() : promisePassed())
})

function promiseFailed(){
  console.log('one or all failed!')
  console.log(promiseErrorArr)
}

function promisePassed(){
  console.log('all passed!')
}

// expected output:
// "one or all failed!"
// Array [Object { status: "rejected", reason: "foo" }]
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of `allSettled`,we can now read the **status of
each promise** is, and process each error individually, **without losing any of this critical information**

```
const promises = [
    fetch('/api/first'), // first
    fetch('/api/second') // second
];
```

The simplest way is to handle errors

```
const [firstResult, secondResult] = await Promise.allSettled(promises)


 // Process first
 if (firstResult.status === 'rejected') {
   const err = firstResult.reason
   // Here you can handle error
 } else {
   const first = firstResult.value
 }

  // Process second
 if (secondResult.status === 'rejected') {
   const err = secondResult.reason
   // Here you can handle error
 } else {
   const second = secondResult.value
 }
```

A nice way to handle error

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
const [first, second] = handleResults(results)


function handleResults(results) {
  const errors = results.filter(result => result.status === 'rejected').map(result => result.reason)

  if (errors.length) {
    // Aggregate all errors into one
    throw new AggregateError(errors)
  }

  return results.map(result => result.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you have a case where you don't particularly care about the values of the resolved promises when there is one failure but you still want them to have run, you could do something like this which will resolve with the promises as normal when they all succeed and reject with the failed promises when any of them fail:

```
function promiseNoReallyAll (promises) {
  return new Promise(
    async (resolve, reject) => {
      const failedPromises = []

      const successfulPromises = await Promise.all(
        promises.map(
          promise => promise.catch(error => {
            failedPromises.push(error)
          })
        )
      )

      if (failedPromises.length) {
        reject(failedPromises)
      } else {
        resolve(successfulPromises)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap your promise returning functions in a way that they catches failure and returning instead an agreed value (e.g. error.message), so the exception won't roll all the way up to the Promise.all function and disable it.

```
async function resetCache(ip) {

    try {

        const response = await axios.get(`http://${ip}/resetcache`);
        return response;

    }catch (e) {

        return {status: 'failure', reason: 'e.message'};
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way (workaround) to do this without making it sync.

So as it was mentioned before `Promise.all` is all of none.

so... Use an enclosing promise to catch and force resolve.

```js
      let safePromises = originalPrmises.map((imageObject) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              // Do something error friendly
              promise.then(_res => resolve(res)).catch(_err => resolve(err))
            })
        })
    })

    // safe
    return Promise.all(safePromises)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know how to identify an error in your results. If you do not have a standard expected error, I suggest that you run a transformation on each error in the catch block that makes it identifiable in your results.

```
try {
  let resArray = await Promise.all(
    state.routes.map(route => route.handler.promiseHandler().catch(e => e))
  );

  // in catch(e => e) you can transform your error to a type or object
  // that makes it easier for you to identify whats an error in resArray
  // e.g. if you expect your err objects to have e.type, you can filter
  // all errors in the array eg
  // let errResponse = resArray.filter(d => d && d.type === '<expected type>')
  // let notNullResponse = resArray.filter(d => d)

  } catch (err) {
    // code related errors
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to error log, but you can always set everything to an array for the promiseAll, and store the resulting results into new variables.

If you use graphQL you need to postprocess the response regardless and if it doesn't find the correct reference it'll crash the app, narrowing down where the problem is at

```
const results = await Promise.all([
  this.props.client.query({
    query: GET_SPECIAL_DATES,
  }),
  this.props.client.query({
    query: GET_SPECIAL_DATE_TYPES,
  }),
  this.props.client.query({
    query: GET_ORDER_DATES,
  }),
]).catch(e=>console.log(e,"error"));
const specialDates = results[0].data.specialDates;
const specialDateTypes = results[1].data.specialDateTypes;
const orderDates = results[2].data.orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to comment (or do much of anything, really), so I'm posting this as an answer in response to [Eric's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929048/17321211).

> The executor function can also be an async function. However, this is usually a mistake, for a few reasons:
>
> - If an async executor function throws an error, the error will be lost and won’t cause the newly-constructed Promise to reject. This could make it difficult to debug and handle some errors.
> - If a Promise executor function is using await, this is usually a sign that it is not actually necessary to use the new Promise constructor, or the scope of the new Promise constructor can be reduced.

[From this explanation as to why **Promises should not utilize an async executor function**](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-async-promise-executor#:%7E:text=The%20executor%20function%20can%20also,debug%20and%20handle%20some%20errors.)

**Instead**, you should opt for [**Promise.allSettled()**, as suggested here by Asaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67283529/17321211).

Answer (score -1):

That's how `Promise.all` is designed to work. If a single promise `reject()`'s, the entire method immediately fails.

There are use cases where one might want to have the `Promise.all` allowing for promises to fail. To make this happen, simply don't use any `reject()` statements in your promise. However, to ensure your app/script does not freeze in case any single underlying promise *never* gets a response, you need to put a timeout on it.

```
function getThing(uid,branch){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        xhr.get().then(function(res) {
            if (res) {
                resolve(res);
            } 
            else {
                resolve(null);
            }
            setTimeout(function(){reject('timeout')},10000)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            resolve(null);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises/36115549#36115549

Comment: Not using `reject()` in your promise is fine, but what if you need to use another library's promises?

Answer (score -9):

I wrote a npm library to deal with this problem more beautiful.
https://github.com/wenshin/promiseallend

### Install

```
npm i --save promiseallend
```

### 2017-02-25 new api, it's not break promise principles

```
const promiseAllEnd = require('promiseallend');

const promises = [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.reject('error'), Promise.resolve(2)];
const promisesObj = {k1: Promise.resolve(1), k2: Promise.reject('error'), k3: Promise.resolve(2)};

// input promises with array
promiseAllEnd(promises, {
    unhandledRejection(error, index) {
        // error is the original error which is 'error'.
        // index is the index of array, it's a number.
        console.log(error, index);
    }
})
    // will call, data is `[1, undefined, 2]`
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    // won't call
    .catch(error => console.log(error.detail))

// input promises with object
promiseAllEnd(promisesObj, {
    unhandledRejection(error, prop) {
        // error is the original error.
        // key is the property of object.
        console.log(error, prop);
    }
})
    // will call, data is `{k1: 1, k3: 2}`
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    // won't call
    .catch(error => console.log(error.detail))

// the same to `Promise.all`
promiseAllEnd(promises, {requireConfig: true})
    // will call, `error.detail` is 'error', `error.key` is number 1.
    .catch(error => console.log(error.detail))

// requireConfig is Array
promiseAllEnd(promises, {requireConfig: [false, true, false]})
    // won't call
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    // will call, `error.detail` is 'error', `error.key` is number 1.
    .catch(error => console.log(error.detail))

// requireConfig is Array
promiseAllEnd(promises, {requireConfig: [true, false, false]})
    // will call, data is `[1, undefined, 2]`.
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    // won't call
    .catch(error => console.log(error.detail))
```

————————————————————————————————

### Old bad api, do not use it!

```
let promiseAllEnd = require('promiseallend');

// input promises with array
promiseAllEnd([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.reject('error'), Promise.resolve(2)])
    .then(data => console.log(data)) // [1, undefined, 2]
    .catch(error => console.log(error.errorsByKey)) // {1: 'error'}

// input promises with object
promiseAllEnd({k1: Promise.resolve(1), k2: Promise.reject('error'), k3: Promise.resolve(2)})
    .then(data => console.log(data)) // {k1: 1, k3: 2}
    .catch(error => console.log(error.errorsByKey)) // {k2: 'error'}
```

Comment: How does it work? Please show and explain your implementation of the function.

Comment: I wrote a new concurrent logic like `Promise.all`. But it will collect all data and errors of every promise. also it support object input, it's not point. after collected all data and errors, I override the `promise.then` method to deal with the callbacks registered which include rejected and fulfilled. For detail you can see [the code](https://github.com/wenshin/promiseallend/blob/master/lib/index.js#L94)

Comment: Uh, that code will call both `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` handlers that are passed to `then`?

Comment: Yes, only when promise status mix `fulfilled` and `rejected`. But really it cause a hard problem to be compatible with all promise use cases normally, like `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` all return `Promise.reject()` or `Promise.resolve()`. So far I'm not clear how to solve it, do any one have better idea? The best answer for now have a problem is, it may can not filter data and errors in browser environment.

Comment: Do we need to install npm module with pip python package manager?

Comment: Sorry I make a spelling mistake, it's not need pip, just `npm i --save promiseallend`