# es6 promises swallow type errors

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want the browser to show an error message when a type error occurs.
errors like **can not read property something of undefined** or **undefined reference**.

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    // do stuff ...
    reject('something logical is wrong');
}).catch(e => console.error(e));

new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    // do stuff, and a syntax error :/
    var a = { };
    a.something.otherthing = 1; /* we have an error here */
    // ... 
}).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

In the first example the error is a logical one, and its fine to **catch** it in the **catch(..)** block.
But in the second example it is a clear development error, which happens all the time while developing new stuff. I don't want to catch it, i want the browser to show me the error like other errors in the console.
I want to be able to turn on **chrome pause on exceptions** and see the state of other variables. I want to see the stack trace in console.
I want it to act like a **normal** error.

Any idea?

Comment: Using your second example, I get the following error in my console `TypeError: Cannot set property 'otherthing' of undefined`. Is this not what you want to happen? The promise is left pending, but thats a different issue.

Comment: i want the line number of error, stack trace .

Comment: @AdamJeffers i want to use *chrome* break on exceptions feature too.

Comment: To get correct line number of error, I think you'll need to remove the catch()? This is an interesting question though, I feel the need to investigate further!!

Comment: FWIW with your example I get line numbers for the `TypeError` in the console in both Chrome and Firefox, and in Firefox I also get a stacktrace in the console.

Comment: This is not a syntax error. It's a `TypeError`. You might want to edit the title of your question.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, DONE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike exceptions in synchronous code, which become *uncaught* as soon as code returns to *idle*, a browser generally doesn't know the logical end of a promise-chain, which is where an *asynchronous error* could be considered uncaught. Chains are dynamically assembled after all, and therefore better be terminated with a final `.catch` at the logical end of the chain i.e. the asynchronous equivalent of idle.

Having a final `.catch(e => console.error(e))` seems very reasonable to me, but you're right that browsers tend to display these errors differently from uncaught exceptions. If you want them to appear the same, you can use this trick:

```
.catch(e => setTimeout(() => { throw e; }))
```

This will throw `e`, containing the original stack trace and line number, on the very next cycle, and outside of the promise chain, where nothing will catch it and it will be reported as uncaught. We use `setTimeout` to overcome the default behavior of `.catch` which is to capture any exceptions in-chain in case you intend to keep on chaining.

With this, I hope you see that any differentiation between "logical" and other errors is irrelevant. Any error that makes it to the tail of the chain was fatal to the chain i.e. *uncaught* (though of course you can triage "logical" from other errors in the final catch and display them differently if you choose.)

Answer (score 2):

**chrome** has an option **Pause on Caught Exceptions** in **Sources** tab, i enabled that option and **Pause on Exceptions** feature is working fine now.

Comment: This will pause on both the logical error and the `TypeError`, so this doesn't seem to fit the criteria of your own question.