# Ajax parallel post: Define timeout for each request and get only suceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

My question is there is a way to define timeout for each parallel ajax post when we used jquery deffered interface. E.g.

```
parallelPost: function(toUrl1, toUrl2, theData1, theData2, contentType, dataType, successHandler, errorHandelr, completeHandler) {

$.when($.ajax(this.createAjaxCall(toUrl1, theData1, true, headers, 'POST', contentType, dataType,1000)),
               $.ajax(this.createAjaxCall(toUrl2, theData2, true, headers, 'POST', contentType, dataType,2000))).done(function(res1, res2) {
                successHandler(res1, res2);
            }, errorHandelr, completeHandler);
        },
        createAjaxCall: function(toUrl, theData, isAsync, headers, verb, contentType, dataType, timeout, successHandler, errorHandelr, completeHandler) {
            return {
                url: toUrl,
                cache: false,
                type: verb,
                data: theData,
                dataType: dataType,
                timeout: timeout || 0,
                async: isAsync,
                headers: headers,
                contentType: contentType ? contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: successHandler,
                error: errorHandelr,
                complete: completeHandler
            };
        }
```

The timeouts for each parallel posts were defined 1000 and 2000. My goal to get those responses that were succeeded in defined timeouts. Thus, when the first request was time-outed and second was not, then return only second response.

Via jquery deffered interface if at least one is time-outed fail callback is called.

Is there is a way to define such behavior or may be another interface that provide solution to issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this ...

First, for the general principle, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/3478010).

Now, implement `reflect()` in the guise of a chainable `.jqXhrReflect()` method, which returns:

- on success: jQuery.ajax success args bundled into a single object,
- on error: a promise resolved with jQuery.ajax error args bundled into a single object.

```
(function($) {
    if(!$.$P) {
        $.$P = function() {
            return (this instanceof $.$P) ? this : (new $.$P());
        };
    }
    if(!$.$P.prototype.jqXhrReflect) {
        $.$P.prototype.jqXhrReflect = function() {
            /* A promise method that "reflects" a jqXHR response.
             * Delivers, on the success path, an object that bundles :
             * - jqXHR success arguments (data, textStatus, xhr) or 
             * - jqXHR error arguments (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown).
             */
            return this.then(
                function(data, textStatus, xhr) { return { 'data':data, 'textStatus':textStatus, 'xhr':xhr }; },
                function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { return $.when({ 'xhr':xhr, 'textStatus':textStatus, 'errorThrown':errorThrown }); }
            );
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

*Note: Custom jQuery promise methods are not intuitive*

Then change `parallelPost()` as follows :

- to accept ready-formed ajax options,
- not to accept successHandler, errorHandelr, completeHandler args,
- to filter the ajax responses in order to separate out results and errors.

```
parallelPost: function(ajaxOptions1, ajaxOptions2) {
    return $.when(
        this.ajaxCall(ajaxOptions1),
        this.ajaxCall(ajaxOptions2)
    ).then(function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // here, apply various filters
        return {
            all: args,
            results: args.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.data !== undefined;
            }),
            allErrors: args.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.errorThrown !== undefined;
            }),
            timeouts: args.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.errorThrown && obj.textStatus === 'timeout';
            }),
            otherErrors: args.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj.errorThrown && obj.textStatus !== 'timeout';
            })
        };
    });
},
```

Then change `.createAjaxCall()` to actually perform the ajax call and transmogrify the response using the `.jqXhrReflect()` method defined above :

```
ajaxCall: function(ajaxOptions) {
    var ajaxDefaults = {
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON', // or whatever
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    return $.ajax($.extend(ajaxDefaults, ajaxOptions)) // $.extend does the necessary magic of merging ajaxDefaults and ajaxOptions.
        .promise($.$P()) // make the .jqXhrReflect() method available.
        .jqXhrReflect(); // call the .jqXhrReflect() method.
}
```

Now you can call,

```
myObj.parallelPost(
    { url: 'path/to/resource1', timeout: 1000 },
    { url: 'path/to/resource2', timeout: 2000 }
).then(function(outcomes) {
    // this success callback is guaranteed to fire and will make the following available :
    // array outcomes.all
    // array outcomes.results
    // array outcomes.allErrors
    // array outcomes.timeouts
    // array outcomes.otherErrors
});
```