# javascript - run promises in parallel but handle rejections separately

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use `bluebird.js` `map` function to perform parallel requests to an external API I use.
whenever any of the inner promises gets rejected, the `map` function also gets rejected (I know that this is by design).
I was wondering if there is any way to run promises in parallel but handle each rejection separately, and not fail the entire Promise.

Comment: The usual thing would be to convert those rejections into resolutions with a flag value. I don't know bluebird's semantics and syntax, though. With ES2015's promises, it would be just `p = p.catch(function(error) { return /*...something to indicate this resolution is really an error..*/;})` (prior to giving `p` to `map`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's `.reflect` - added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `.reflect` with the map to get promise inspections as the result:

```
const all = Promise.map(items, item => doSomething(item).reflect());

all.then(items => {
  // will contain an array of the promises that fulfilled correctly
  let fulfilled = items.filter(x => x.isFulfilled()).map(x => x.value()));
  // will contain an array of the promises that rejected 
  // so you can handle the errors
  let rejected = items.filter(x => x.isRejected()).map(x => x.reason());

});
```

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is any way to run promises in parallel but handle each rejection separately, and not fail the entire Promise.

Sure there is - just handle them using [`catch`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) or [`error`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html):

```
const all = Promise.map(somethings, function(something) {
    return doSomething(something).catch(function(e) {
        return handleIt(e); // normal completion, no rejection or exception
    });
});
```

See also [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/1048572) in general.

Comment: `Promise.map` is not a standard api. Please add which npm package you are using for Promises.

Comment: @zoran404 The question is tagged [tag:Bluebird] so that's what I was using. The answers in the linked question work with native promises though

Comment: Ok and sorry, I was looking for answers and didn't read the question after the title :)

Answer (score -1):

Without any library with pure ES6 promises you may have an approach like this. In this case the `promiseAll` function would honor resolved promises along with the rejected ones.

```js
function promisify(fun){
  return (data) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => fun(data, (err,res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)));
}

function async(data, callback){
  data.val+= " msec";
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? setTimeout(_ => callback(false,data.val),data.dur)
                      : setTimeout(_ => callback("error"),data.dur);
}

function myNormalCallback(resultObject){
  console.log("Promise " + resultObject.count + " returned " + resultObject.result);
}

function myErrorCallback(errorObject){
  console.log("Promise " + errorObject.count + " returned " + errorObject.error);
}

function promiseAll(proms){
  return new Promise((v,x) => { var results = new Array(proms.length).fill(void 0);
                                proms = proms.map((prom,i) => prom.then(res  => {results[i] = res;
                                                                                 results.indexOf(void 0) === -1 && v(results);
                                                                                })
                                                                  .catch(err => {results[i] = err;
                                                                                 results.indexOf(void 0) === -1 && v(results);
                                                                                }));
                              });
}

var datas = [{val: 100, dur: 1000},{val: 200, dur: 2000},{val: 300, dur: 3000}],
    proms = datas.map(data => promisify(async)(data));
promiseAll(proms).then(results => results.map((res,i) => res === "error" ? myErrorCallback({count:i,error: res})
                                                                         : myNormalCallback({count:i,result: res})));
```