# Angular 1.X - add promise handlers to catch errors on retrieving asynchronous data from multiple functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Suppose within my controller I have a few async methods and I use $q.all to wait for all of them to complete. How do I add error handling to one of the methods in case the data retrieval fails and assure $q.all gets called with the other data and appropriate error message for the one that failed?

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$q', function($scope, $q) {

var promises = [];
var controller_data;

promises.push(assyncMethod1());
promises.push(assyncMethod2());

$q.all(promises).then(function () {
.... 

})

function assyncMethod1() {
 return $http.get("data.json").success( function(data) {
  controller_data = data; 
 });
 //on error?
}

function assyncMethod2() {
 return $http.get("data2.json").success( function(data) {
 ...
 });
 //on error?
}


}]);
```

I know for single promises you would use:

```
//basic version
promise.then(fnSuccess)
  .catch(fnFailure) //optional
  .finally(fnAlways) //optional
```

But how would you do this for multiple functions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is the same, or at least very similar, to this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises, You just need to interpret from ES6 to $q but that is pretty trivial.

Comment: I think that question involves continuing regardless if one fails where I'm asking to continue and display which one failed

Comment: see if this helps http://plnkr.co/edit/l3xOVkMQlOtPXz5srkw0?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl Thankyou this was what I was looking for

Comment: So I was right in the first place. Voted to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises)