# Why does JavaScript's `Promise.all` not run all promises in failure conditions?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> If any of the passed in promises rejects, the all Promise immediately rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, discarding all the other promises whether or not they have resolved.

The [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromiseall) seems to confirm this.

My question is: **Why does `Promise.all` discard promises if any of them reject, since I would expect it to wait for "all" promises to settle**, and what exactly does "discard" mean? (It's hard to tell what "discard" means for in-flight promises vs. promises that may not have run yet.)

I ask because I frequently run into situations where I have a list of promises and want to wait for them *all* to settle and get *all* rejections that may have occurred, which `Promise.all` doesn't cater to. Instead, I have to use a hack like this:

```js
const promises = []; // Array of promises
const settle = promise => promise.then(result => ({ result }), reason => ({ reason }));
Promise.all(promises.map(settle))
  .then(/ * check "reason" property in each element for rejection */);
```

Comment: Questions that ask "why was this not designed the way I want" rarely (perhaps never) provide a satisfying answer.  The answer is pretty much always: "because the designer thought a different way was more useful".  That was their opinion.  You have your opinion.  The two will not always match.

Comment: @jfriend00 There's no one designer. Specs are arrived at through consensus. I think there are good reasons. SO may not be the best place for authorative answers though, unless you want to dig through minutes.

Comment: The word "discard" used in the MDN article is unfortunate. Probably "ignore", or "not worry about", or "not doing anything further with", would be a better choice of words. Fixed. Anyway, you say *Instead, I have to use a hack like this*. Why do you call that a hack?

Comment: @jib - Yeah, I should have said "designers" (plural) to include all the people who participated.  The point is they had a consensus that was different than the OP wanted.  The "why" they had that consensus would probably be found only by sifting through hundreds of communications among the participants or finding one of the principals and asking them why they chose it this way.  In any case, it would be pretty rare if it was something we could answer here (one of the principals familiar with the decision making process would have to accidentally wander by and answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asynchronous operations associated with the promises are all run.  If one of those promises rejects, then `Promise.all()` simply does not wait for all of them to complete, it rejects when the first promise rejects.  That is just how it was designed to work.  If you need different logic (like you want to wait for all of them to be done, no matter whether they fulfill or reject), then you can't use just `Promise.all()`.

Remember, a promise is not the async operation itself.  A promise is just an object that keeps track of the state of the async operation.  So, when you pass an array of promises to `Promise.all()`, all those async operations have already been started and are all in-flight already.  They won't be stopped or cancelled.

> Why does Promise.all discard promises if any of them reject, since I would expect it to wait for "all" promises to settle.

It works the way it does because that's how it was designed and that is a very common use case when you don't want your code to continue if there was any sort of error.  If it happens to not be your use case, then you need to use some implementation of `.settle()` which has the behavior you want (which you seem to already know).

What I find the more interesting question is why is there not a `.settle()` option in the specification and standard implementation since it is also a fairly common use case.  Fortunately, as you have found, it is not a lot of code to make your own.  When I don't need the actual reject reason and just want some indicator value to be placed into the array, I often use this fairly simple to use version:

```
// settle all promises.  For rejeted promises, return a specific rejectVal that is
// distinguishable from your successful return values (often null or 0 or "" or {})
Promise.settleVal = function(rejectVal, promises) {
    return Promise.all(promises.map(function(p) {
        // make sure any values or foreign promises are wrapped in a promise
        return Promise.resolve(p).catch(function(err) {
            // instead of rejection, just return the rejectVal (often null or 0 or "" or {})
            return rejectVal;
        });
    }));
};

// sample usage:
Promise.settleVal(null, someArrayOfPromises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(r) {
        // log successful ones
        if (r !== null) {
           console.log(r);
        }
    });
});
```

> what exactly does "discard" mean?

It just means that the promises are no longer tracked by `Promise.all()`.  The async operations they are associated with keep right on doing whatever they were going to do.   And, in fact if those promises have `.then()` handlers on them, they will be called just as they normally would.  `discard` does seem like an unfortunate term to use here.  Nothing happens other than `Promise.all()` stops paying attention to them.

---

FYI, if I want a more robust version of `.settle()` that keeps track of all results and reject reasons, then I use this:

```
// ES6 version of settle that returns an instanceof Error for promises that rejected
Promise.settle = function(promises) {
    return Promise.all(promises.map(function(p) {
        // make sure any values or foreign promises are wrapped in a promise
        return Promise.resolve(p).catch(function(err) {
            // make sure error is wrapped in Error object so we can reliably detect which promises rejected
            if (err instanceof Error) {
                return err;
            } else {
                var errObject = new Error();
                errObject.rejectErr = err;
                return errObject;
            }
        });
    }));
}

// usage
Promise.settle(someArrayOfPromises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(r) {
       if (r instanceof Error) {
           console.log("reject reason", r.rejectErr);
       } else {
           // fulfilled value
           console.log("fulfilled value:", r);
       }
    });
});
```

This resolves to an array of results.  If a result is instanceof Error, then it was a rejected, otherwise it's a fulfilled value.

Comment: Your "more interesting question" is what I was attempting to get at by asking my original question, similarly wondering why something like a `.allSettle()` doesn't exist in the language since that also seems like a common use case. I asked the question partly because I thought maybe there was a better way to address that use case that I was missing.

Comment: @segfault - yeah, having no `.settle()` or `.allSettle()` seems like an odd omission from the original standard.  Fortunately, it's not a lot of code to make your own.  The Bluebird promise library has added [`.reflect()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html) which gives you access to this type of functionality fairly easily, though you still code your own `.settle()`.  Bluebird used to have a `.settle()`, but they removed it for reasons I don't know.

Answer (score 8):

Because `Promise.all` guarantees they all succeeded. Simple as that.

It's the most useful building block along with `Promise.race`. Everything else can be built on those.

There's no `settle`, because it's so trivial to build [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36115549/918910):

```
Promise.all([a(), b(), c()].map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
```

There's no easy way to build `Promise.all` on top of `settle`, which may be why it's not the default. `settle` would also have had to standardize a way to distinguish success values from errors, which may be subjective and depend on the situation.

**Update:** There's now a [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) that does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue, because rejecting a promise is like throwing an error in sync code, and an uncatched error in sync code also interrupts the execution.

Or one could argue for the assumption that requesting all these promises and composing them into a combined Array, and then waiting for all these to finish implies that you need them all to proceed with whatever you've intended to do, and if one of them fails your intended task lacks one of its dependencies, and it is logical to simply forward the reason for the fail till this reason is somehow handled/caught.