# Promise with array is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling 2 functions using Promise.all function, where I am passing an odd number and an even number. Based on the number I am deciding the success or failure.

```
const time11=(t) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
   if(t%2==0){
     resolve(t)
   }else{
     reject(t)
   }
  })
}

// Promise.all
Promise.all([time11(101), time11(1210)])
 .then(result => console.log('success',result))
 .catch(error=> console.log('error',error))
```

I expect the output is **success 1210** and **error 101**, but the actual output is **error 101**.

Comment: `[time11(101), time11(1210)].forEach(p => p
 .then(result => console.log('success',result))
 .catch(error=> console.log('error',error))
)`

Comment: `Promise.all` only resolves if ALL passed promises resolve, it rejects everything as you see. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Check out `Promise.allSettled()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript's \`Promise.all\` not run all promises in failure conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304394/why-does-javascripts-promise-all-not-run-all-promises-in-failure-conditions)

Comment: Or [Wait until all promises complete even if some rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/215552)

Answer (score 1):

## [`Promise#allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

> The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either resolved or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

```js
const time11=(t) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
   if(t%2==0){
     resolve(t)
   }else{
     reject(t)
   }
  })
}

Promise
.allSettled([time11(101), time11(1210)])
.then(result =>console.log(result));
```

However, only supported in a [few browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled#Browser_compatibility) at the moment. Above snippet will only work with latest version of chrome.

Output, will look something like so:

```
[
  {
    "status": "rejected",
    "reason": 101
  },
  {
    "status": "fulfilled",
    "value": 1210
  }
]
```

Here is to separate the errors from the successes.

```js
const time11=(t) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
   if(t%2==0){
     resolve(t)
   }else{
     reject(t)
   }
  })
}

Promise
.allSettled([time11(101), time11(1210)])
.then(result =>{
  const [success, errors] = result.reduce(([success, errors],cur)=>{
    if(cur.status === 'fulfilled'){
      success.push(cur);
    } else {
      errors.push(cur);
    }
    return [success, errors];
  }, [[],[]]);
  
  console.log('errors', errors);
  console.log('success', success);
});
```

Comment: Hi kemicofa, Thanks for the suggestion but unfortuntely Promise.allSettled function is not available in node js.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as one of them rejects. In other words, it either resolves with an array of all resolved values, or rejects with a single error.

Some libraries have something called Promise.when, which I understand would instead wait for all promises in the array to either resolve or reject, but I'm not familiar with it, and it's not in ES6.

In this case, you can `resolve` all cases, but you must manage different based in the response at the `then` chain.

```
const time11=(t) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
   if(t%2==0){
     resolve(true) // Changed to boolean
   }else{
     resolve(false)  // Resolved and Boolean
   }
  })
}

// Promise.all
Promise.all([time11(101), time11(1210)])
 .then(isEven => console.log('isEven',isEven))
```