# Javascript Promises - get Array of non rejected

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I need a function that can take an `Array<Promise<Object>>` and return an `Promise<Array<Object>>`.

It would be similar to a `Promise.all()`, but instead of failing on a `reject` it just ignores them, and moves on.

Comment: and your code is?

Comment: are you sure you don't mean `Array<Promise<Object>>` to `Promise<Array<Object>>`?

Comment: What is `Promises<…>`?

Comment: Just use `Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(err => undefined)))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises)?

Comment: There are no blocking functions that wait for promises. Fortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to transform an `Array<Promise<X>>` to a `Promise<Array<X>>`.

To ignore rejections, just handle them and return some null value instead:

```
Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(err => undefined)))
```

If you are interested in completely filtering them out, use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/1048572) that post-processes the array.

Answer (score 0):

We went with the solution described by @Bergi, you can see it [here](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-hub-client/blob/bd405aa41fba0706bf80a27eceead241c7954ebb/src/scripts/utils/media.js#L33).

Slightly simplified example follows:

```
function preloadImages(imagePromises) {
  const IMAGE_LOAD_FAIL = null;

  const promises = imagePromises
    .map(image => image.catch(err => IMAGE_LOAD_FAIL));

  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(images =>  images.filter(image => image !== IMAGE_LOAD_FAIL));
}
```