# Javascript Promise.all - how to handle all errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

How can I handle errors from other than first promise rejection?

Example:

```
Promise.all[p1, p2, p3].then(...)
.catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
```

Order of rejection:
`p1`
`p2`
`p3`

Is it possible to get errors from `p2` and `p3`?

EDIT:
from comments below: is it possible to `catch` error from specific Promise before passing it to `.all`? E.g. I want to stay with `Promise.all` funcionality but log all error cases also

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be only one rejected promise. No more. You'll receive error for the first one rejected and that's it.

Comment: This isn't true. Any or all of the promises may reject, but regardless of how many reject, only the first one's error is mad available to `catch`.

Comment: And you can catch each one before passing to all()

Comment: Yes, of course all of them may reject, but i meant that there will be only one error object of one rejected promise.