# Handling Errors (Rejections) in async/await inside Array#map

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

Node 8.1.2, I have a structure where one file is calling another file's function in a map. In a real example I would use `Promise.all` on the `map` but that's not the question here. Here is the structure:

`A.js:`

```
const { b } = require('./B')

function expressStuff (req, res, next) {
  things.map(thing => {
    return b(thing)
  }))

  return res.status(200).json(...)
}
```

`B.js:`

```
// Thing -> Promise<Object>
function b (thing) {
  return ThingModel.update(...) // this returns a Promise but FAILS and throws an errror
}

module.exports = { b }
```

OK. So in function `b` I try to get some async data (from a database). It fails and throws an Uncaught Promise Rejection.

How to make deal with it?

I tried multiple solutions:

`A1.js:`

```
const { b } = require('./B')

function expressStuff (req, res, next) {
  things.map(thing => {
    try {
      return b(thing)
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
  }))

  return res.status(200).json(...)
}
```

But that is still uncaught.

`A2.js`:

```
const { b } = require('./B')

function expressStuff (req, res, next) {

  try {
    things.map(thing => {
      return b(thing)
    }))
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err)
  }

  return res.status(200).json(...)
}
```

Still unhandled. I tried using `Promise.all`, I tried double try-catch blocks (since I thought the one inside `map` might be returning `next` from the to the `map` result and not actually from `expressStuff` function. Still nothing.

The closes I got to the answer was handling the error but then code wouldn't wait for it to be thrown and both `res.status()` and `next` would work resulting in race conditions and `cannot set headers after they are sent` errors.

All I want to do is for the function `b` to throw an error but catch it in the `expressStuff` so I can rethrow custom `UnprocessableEntityError` and pass it to `next`. It seems like error from file `B` is not bubbling up to the `map` where it is called.

How do I do it?

EDIT:

The only way I can make this rejection handled is try-catching it in the `B.js`. But if I try to rethrow an error/return it - nothing. Error is swallowed. If I try to `console.log` it - it will be logged though.

DETAILS:

Thanks to marked answer I refactored my actual code and made it to work perfectly.

```
function expressStuff (res, req, next) {
  try {
    await Promise.all(things.map(async thing => {
      if (ifSomething()) {
        await b(thing)
      }
    }))
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new MyCustomError('My Custom Error Message'))
  }

  return res.status(200).json(...)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handling rejections with `try`/`catch` works only in `async function`s when you `await` the promise - which you haven't attempted yet.

You could do either

```
async function expressStuff (req, res, next) {
  var results;
  try {
    results = await Promise.all(things.map(b)); // throws when any of the promises reject
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err) // handle error
  }
  return res.status(200).json(...)
}
```

or (like [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises))

```
function expressStuff (req, res, next) {
  const resultPromises = things.map(async (thing) => {
    try {
      return await b(thing); // throws when the promise for this particular thing rejects
    } catch (err) {
      return defaultValue; // handle error - don't call `next` here
    }
  });
  …
  return res.status(200).json(...)
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. That's a great suggestion! But this still has a problem of `Can't set headers after they are sent.`, because `return next(err)` and `return res.status(200)` are both trying to execute. Any idea on that?

Comment: @TomaszGałkowski Are you sure you have both returns in the same function, like in my answer?

Comment: Yes, positive. It's an async function that `awaits` for one thing and later does that map. After the map it returns 200. If an error occurs within the map it should return `next` with my custom error - and send 422. Which it tries to do now, thanks to you. But that's where the double headers seem to come from.

Comment: You must not call `next` within the `map` callback, it might happen multiple times in there. And if you `return` after `next()`, it won't execute `res.status()`. Please post the updated code that is causing the error

Comment: Actually that last comment made me reformat the code and find the error. I had one more `if` clause inside the `map` so I moved the `await Promise.all()` to take in the whole map. I will post the details in the question and mark your response as answer as it perfectly answered my initial question.