# Javascript - How to pass data from two API ajax calls to one function

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I am attempting to make two seperate ajax calls to a third party API end point and display both its data on a HighChart graph. I am attempting to pass the data from both calls into my `drawHighcharts` function in order to display the data.

I am having issues with properly passing the data from both ajax calls. I've attempted to call back my `drawHighcharts` function in both my ajax calls. When console.logging both data I am only seeing the first `stData` but the `odData` is returning undefined. I am returning back `stData` twice and I believe that is because I am calling my function twice.

What is the proper way of handling both data into one function?

My expected outcome is to be able to access `odData and stData` in my `drawHighCharts` function.

```
function getStData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: stUrl,
        async: true,
        success: function (stData) {
            drawHighCharts(stData)

        },
        error: function (e) {
            // handle exception
            console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
        }
    });
}

function getOdData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: odUrl,
        async: true,
        success: function (odData) {
            drawHighCharts(odData)
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // handle exception
            console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
        }
    });
}

function drawHighCharts(stData, odData) {
    console.log(stData, "st")

    console.log(odData, "od")


}
```

Comment: I suppose, your functions `getOdData` shall return the Promise from `$.ajax$`, i.e. `return $.ajax({..});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because in your ajax calls you're only passing one argument. In `getStData` you're passing only `stData` to `drawHighCharts` and for `getOdData` you're only passing `odData`. It would make sense why in the `drawHighCharts` function one of the two arguments (the second one) is undefined since you're only passing one argument. Instead, you can wrap multiple get requests in `Promise.all`. This way your requests will be made and when they are both finished the promise will resolve and you can access both API results in the `then` following the `Promise.all`. See below.

```
function getStData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: stUrl,
        async: true,
        success: function (stData) {
            return stData

        },
        error: function (e) {
            // handle exception
            console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
        }
    });
}

function getOdData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: odUrl,
        async: true,
        success: function (odData) {
            return odData
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // handle exception
            console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
        }
    });
}

function drawHighCharts(stData, odData) {
    console.log(stData, "st")
    console.log(odData, "od")
}



Promise.all([
  getStData(),
  getOdData(),
]).then(([stData, odData]) => drawHighCharts(stData, odData))
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241827/fetch-api-requesting-multiple-get-requests) is related to `fetch` requests in React but `Promise.all` can be used with ajax in regular JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getOdData()` inside success of `getStData()` and pass stData to it. And then inside success of `getOdData()` you will have access to both  stData and odData. Now you can call `drawHighCharts()` with both stData and odData.