# React Promise All Multiple APIs, Different Error Handling

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wanted to run different error handling with React Promise.
API 1 and 2 should have different error handlings.

1. Execute APIs all at once to save time.
2. Run different error handling statements for each API as soon as possible, without waiting for the others.
3. Each API should continue even if one fails.

How can this be done?

**Reference:**

[Fetch API requesting multiple get requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241827/fetch-api-requesting-multiple-get-requests)

```
Promise.all([
            fetch(api1).then(value => value.json()),
            fetch(api2).then(value => value.json())
            ])
            .then((value) => {
               console.log(value)
              //json response
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is just wrapping up whatever promises you give it - so there's no reason you couldn't handle the errors separately for each one. For example, you could create a separate function for each of the fetches - you could even throw a custom error here that dictates some sort of "followUp" action to do, or identifies where the error is from, or anything (you can throw anything in javascript):

```js
const fetchFromApi1 = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(api1);
    return response.json();

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('API 1 failed');
    
    // Throw a custom error
    throw {
      errorSource: 'API_CALL_1',
      message: 'API call 1 failed',
    };
  }
};

const fetchFromApi2 = async () => {
  // ----- 8< -----
};
```

Then you can just combine them in your your `Promise.all` - if you've thrown a custom error as above, you can use that to work out what to do:

```js
const fetchAllTheThings = async () => {
  try {
    const [response1, response2] = await Promise.all([
      fetchFromApi1(),
      fetchFromApi2(),
    ]);

  } catch (err) {
    const { errorSource, message } = err;
    // do something....
  }
};
```

---

##### Edit

If you want to know which promise failed at the point of calling, you're probably better off using [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) -

```js
const fetchAllTheThings = async () => {
  const [result1, result2] = await Promise.allSettled([
    fetchFromApi1(),
    fetchFromApi2(),
  ]);

  if (result1.status === 'rejected') {
    // Sad for promise 1
  }

  if (result2.status === 'rejected') {
    // Sad for promise 2
  }
};
```

Comment: on the final catch block, how do I differentiate between Error from API1 vs Error from API2? Our program will require different steps

Comment: @mattsmith5 - you're probably better off using `allSettled` - see edit

Comment: See I want to handle all errors as they come in for each api, not when  all the apis are completed , will all settled handle that?

Comment: No, `allSettled` will resolve when all the promises have settled (as the name implies ). You could always throw a custom `Error` in each `fetchFromApi...()` implementations, then inspect it in the outer-most error handler and work out what to do. Edits added above.

Comment: "... each API should continue even if one fails." - the only way to do that would be use `allSettled`; `all` will fail as soon as one of the promises fails. You might need a bit of a combination of the approaches outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const p1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res("p1 success")
  }, 1000)
})
const p2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res("p2 success")
  }, 3000)
})
const p3 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    rej("p3 failed")
  }, 1000)
})
const p4 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    rej("p4 failed")
  }, 2000)
})

Promise.allSettled([p1, p2, p3, p4])
  .then(console.log)
```