# i need to returns a `Promise` that is fulfilled when all promises in `input` * are settled (meaning, either resolved or rejected)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

promiseSettle must returns a `Promise` that is fulfilled when all promises in `input` are settled (meaning, either resolved or rejected).

The fulfillment value will be an array of objects, each having the following signature:

- @typedef {Object} Settlement
- @property {boolean} isFulfilled - whether the promise resolved
- @property {boolean} isRejected - whether the promise rejected
- @property {*=} value - the value (if any) with which the promise was resolved
- @property {*=} reason - the reason (if any) with which the promise was rejected
- @param {Array.>} input - an array of Promises
- @return {Promise.>}

  ```
  function promiseSettle(input) {
      let promiseArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          Promise.resolve(input[i]).then(output => {
              promiseArray.push(output);
              console.log(promiseArray);
          }, reason => {
              promiseArray.push(reason);
          })    
      }
  }

  // testing data
  var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(reject, 1, "first promise of 1 sec");
  });
  var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1, "second promise of 2 sec");
  })
  var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1, "rejected promise");
  })
  promiseSettle([p1, p2, p3])
  ```

Can someone help with this? I am not sure how to return the promise with the expected parameters.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. like this: `for(let i =0;i{ ` is not even valid code. Please clean it up.

Comment: IS this what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/125981

Comment: "settle" sounds like you might have something else involved not tagged perhaps? OR just the mashed up sudo code?

Comment: @Intervalia : Could you help with the solution . i have cleaned it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```js
function promiseSettle(inputList) {
  let promiseArray = inputList.map(
    input => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        input.then(
          value => {
            resolve({
              isFulfilled: true,
              isRejected: false,
              value
            });
          },
          reason => {
            resolve({
              isFulfilled: false,
              isRejected: true,
              reason
            });
          }

        );
      });
    }
  );
  
  return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}

// testing data
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1, "first promise of 1 sec");
});
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2, "second promise of 2 sec");
})
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(reject, 1, "rejected promise");
})

promiseSettle([p1, p2, p3]).then(
  promises => {
    console.log(promises);
  }
);
```