# Wait for all different promise to finish nodejs (async await)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently waiting for all the promise to finish sequentially like this:

```
(async() => {
  let profile = await profileHelper.getUserData(username);
   let token = await tokenHelper.getUserToken(username);
   console.log(profile);
   console.log(token);
   return {profile: profile, token: token};
})();
```

But this way, profile and token executes sequentially. Since both are independent of each other, I want both of them to be executed independently together. I think this can be done using Promise.all, but I am not sure of the syntax and I could not find any help as well.

So my question is how I can convert above api calls to run together and then return the final output.

Comment: `let [profile, token] = await Promise.all([profileHelper.getUserData(username), tokenHelper.getUserToken(username)])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1641941

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
(async() => {
  const [ profile, token ] = await Promise.all([
    profileHelper.getUserData(username),
    tokenHelper.getUserToken(username)
  ]);

  return { profile, token };
})();
```

Comment: Both the answers were almost at same time with almost same explanation.. so choosing randomly.

Answer (score 15):

use `Promise.all()` method:

```
(async() => {
 let [ profile, token ] = await Promise.all(
  [profileHelper.getUserData(username), 
  tokenHelper.getUserToken(username)
 ])
 return {profile: profile, token: token};
})();
```

[Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises)

Comment: Both the answers were almost at same time with almost same explanation.. so choosing randomly.

Answer (score 10):

You want to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that resolves
>   when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or
>   when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the
>   reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
(async() => {
  const response = await Promise.all([
    profileHelper.getUserData(username),
    tokenHelper.getUserToken(username)
  ]);

  return {profile: response[0], token: response[1]};
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Promise.all method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the argument have resolved or when the argument contains no promises.

```
exports.getServerDetails = async (req, res, next) => {
var getCount = [];
const [ onlineUser, countSchool ] = await Promise.all([
    getOnlineUsers(), // online user count
    getRegisterUser(), // register user
    getRegisterSchools(), // register school count
]);
getCount = [
            {"Online Users": onlineUser},
            {"Registered Users" : countSchool}
        ];
sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {
    status: 'success',
    data: getCount
})
}
async function getOnlineUsers() {
return Login.count({'onlineStatus': 1}, (err, count) => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
    return count;
});
}

async function getRegisterUser() {
return Login.count({}, (err, totResUser) => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
    return totResUser;
})
}

async function getRegisterSchools() {
return Login.count({'role': 'Admin'},(err, totalSchool) => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
    return totalSchool;
})
}
```