# How can I understand about the Promise all in this case?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I want do a sync task and have tried something like the code bellow, It isn't same what I thought about the Promise before, can you explain this one for me?

```js
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Promise 2');
  resolve();
});

var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Promise 1');
  resolve();
});

Promise.all([p1]).then(p2);
```

It always output the "Promise 2" before "Promise 1".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for all different promise to finish nodejs (async await)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663080/wait-for-all-different-promise-to-finish-nodejs-async-await)

Comment: You pass a function reference to `.then()`.  You don't pass a promise to `.then()`.

Comment: It's good point @jfriend00, your comment make everything clear on my mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `new Promise`, the function you pass into it (the *promise executor*) is run **immediately**, before you receive the promise back and store it in your variable. The reason for that is that the promise executor function's job is to **start** an asynchronous process. It can't start it if it isn't called. That's why you see "Promise 2" before "Promise 1", because that's the order you're calling `new Promise`.

Also note that `Promise.all` doesn't start anything. It just watches the processes that are already in progress and reports on the outcome.

Here's a more realistic use of `new Promise` that may help you understand the timing of things: Starting a timer and resolving the promise when the timer fires:

```js
function timer(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log(`promise executor called for value "${value}"`);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`timer completed for value "${value}", resolving promise`);
            resolve(value);
        }, ms);
    });
}

// Note that I never do anything with the promise `timer` returns
// here, but since it's already started by the time
// it returns, it still does something
console.log("creating anonymous");
timer(800, "anonymous");

console.log("creating p1");
const p1 = timer(1600, "p1");
console.log("creating p2");
const p2 = timer(2400, "p2");
console.log("calling Promise.all([p1, p2])");
Promise.all([p1, p2])
.then(results => {
    console.log(`Promise.all promise reseolved with "${JSON.stringify(results)}"`);
})
.catch(error => {
    // Normally you'd handle errors here, it's just
    // that the promsies from `timer` are never rejected
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to put those strings into the resolve method and then you'll get.  what you want. The console.logs inside the actual promises are not asynchronous.

```
 var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   resolve('Promise 2');
 });

 var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   resolve('Promise 1');
 });

 Promise.all([p1]).then(res1 => {
   console.log(res1);
   return p2
 }).then(res2 => console.log(res2))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` is as its name suggests used to wait that all promises you pass to it get fulfilled.

But since you only want to wait that `p1` fulfills, just add `.then()` to `p1`:

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log('Promise 1');
   resolve('Promise 1');
 }).then()
```

The `Promise.prototype.then()` method returns a promise. So why not simply put whatever you want to put in `p2` in the callback you pass to `then()`, like so:

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       console.log('Promise 1');
       resolve();
     }).then((value) => console.log('Promise 2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to show you that you would have output even if you never used `Promise.all` or `.then` -

```js
const makePromise = x =>
  new Promise(r =>
    ( console.log("constructing...", x)
    , setTimeout(r, 2000, x)  // fake 2 second delay
    )
  )

const a = makePromise("a")
const b = makePromise("b")
const c = makePromise("c")

console.log("construction complete!")

// constructing... "a"
// constructing... "b"
// constructing... "c"
// construction complete!
```

Above, we construct three (3) promises and output is displayed even though we never used `a`, `b`, or `c` anywhere else in the program.

When we attach `.then(handler)` the resolved values are passed to `handler` -

```js
const makePromise = x =>
  new Promise(r =>
    ( console.log("constructing...", x)
    , setTimeout(r, 2000, x)
    )
  )

const a = makePromise("a")
const b = makePromise("b")
const c = makePromise("c")

console.log("construction complete!")

// constructing... "a"
// constructing... "b"
// constructing... "c"
// construction complete!

Promise.all([a, b, c])
  .then(r => console.log("done!", r))
  .catch(e => console.error("error!", e))

// done!
```

This could mean `.then` is called on your promise *way* later in your program, perhaps even asynchronously -

```js
const makePromise = x =>
  new Promise(r =>
    ( console.log("constructing...", x)
    , setTimeout(r, 2000, x)
    )
  )

const a = makePromise("a")
const b = makePromise("b")
const c = makePromise("c")

console.log("construction complete!")

// constructing... "a"
// constructing... "b"
// constructing... "c"
// construction complete!

const main = () =>
  Promise.all([a, b, c])
    .then(r => console.log("done!", r))
    .catch(e => console.error("error!", e))

console.log("please wait 5 seconds...")
setTimeout
  ( _ =>
      ( console.log("calling main() now...")
      , main()
      )
  , 5000
  )


// calling main() now...
// done
```

We wrote `makePromise` to artificially delay the resolved value by two seconds (`2000` milliseconds in the program).

What's critical to notice in this final program is that two seconds begins immediately. By the time we call `Promise.all(...).then(...)` five seconds later, all of our Promises have already resolved a value. This is why we see `"done"` immediately after `main()` is called.