# Return all resolved promises from set of promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

We know that `Promise.all` returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

Is it possible to return all resolved promises and skip rejected ones?

UPD: 
Thank you all) 
This duplicate question  solved with [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises)

Comment: I could not be understand your question completely can you bit explain more

Comment: It means ksoze you want only resolved promise result not rejected promise result.

Comment: Would you mind show your purpose to take this type of actions?

Comment: Thank you  solved with: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises