# Run parallel saga effects without cancelling any of them

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I'd like to run parallel effects with redux-saga, without throwing if an error happens.

Using the `all` effect from redux-saga, if:

> One of the Effects was rejected before all the effects complete: throws the rejection error inside the Generator.

Basically, I want to wait for all effects to finish to trigger an action. I want to do something like this, but replacing `all` by something else:

```
export function* getSaga() {
  yield put(request());
  try {
    yield all([fetchItems1, fetchItems2, fetchItems3]);
    // Wait for all to resolve or get rejected, then dispatch succeed.
    yield put(actions.succeeded());
  } catch (e) {
    // This should never happen.
  }
}
```

I tried to use `fork` but it does cancel all other tasks if one failed. And I tried to use `spawn` but it doesn't wait for the tasks to finish to dispatch `succeeded`.

Using regular JS, there is a pattern called [reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises) which I'd like to apply with saga.

How can we achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following the answer from the linked stackoverflow issue you can just as easily create a `reflect` saga and use it in the same way:

```
function* reflect(saga) {
  try {
    return { v: yield call(saga), status: 'fulfilled' }
  } catch (err) {
    return { e: err, status: 'rejected' }
  }
}
...
yield all([fetchItems1, fetchItems2, fetchItems3].map(reflect));
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2vx74jzqv