# Type annotating reflectPromise method

Tags: typescript

I was trying to type annoate a version of the `reflect` promise method from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/1828637

```
function reflectPromise(p){
    return p.then(data => ({
                data,
                resolved: true
             }))
            .catch(error => ({
                error,
                rejected: true
             }));
}
```

What it does is takes a promise, and returns another promise when it is resolved or rejected.

The things I'm trying to do with pseudocode:

1. Declare that `data` is `typeof ResolveValue(p)`
2. Declare that `error` is `typeof RejectValue(p)`
3. Declare that others can test `const didReject = !!(await (reflectedPromise(somePromise)).rejected` (what this will do for resolved promises, which returns `{ data: xxx, resolved:true }`) is turn `undefined` to `true`. Currently when I do `!!blah.rejected` TypeScript says to me `Property 'rejected' does not exist on type`

This is what I have so far:

```
function reflectPromise(p: Promise<any>): Promise<
        { data: any, resolved: boolean, rejected: void  } |
        { error: any, resolved: void, rejected: boolean }
    > {
    return p.then(data: any) => ({
                data,
                resolved: true
             }))
            .catch((error: any) => ({
                error,
                rejected: true
             }));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a generic type to have the type of the result inferred. The type of the error is considered `any` in Typescript and there is no type safety there. Also I would type `rejected` and `resolved` as `undefined` not `void` (their value will be undefined after all at runtime so it's more acurate) and I would make them optional when they are not present.

Also when `resolve` and `reject` are `true`, I would type them as the boolean literal type `true` in order to allow type-guards to work better.

Putting it together, this compiles (with strict null checks):

```
function reflectPromise<T>(p: Promise<T>): Promise<
        { data: T, resolved: boolean, rejected?: undefined  } |
        { error: any, resolved?: undefined, rejected: boolean }
    > {
    return p.then((data: any) => ({
                data,
                resolved: true
            }))
            .catch((error: any) => ({
                error,
                rejected: true
            }));
}


(async function (somePromise: Promise<number>) {
    const result = await (reflectPromise(somePromise));
    const didReject = !!result.rejected
    if (result.rejected) {
        result.error // result is { error: any, resolved?: undefined, rejected: true }
    } else {
        result.data // result { data: number, resolved: true, rejected?: undefined  } 
    }

    if (result.resolved) {
        result.data // result { data: number, resolved: true, rejected?: undefined  } 
    } else {
        result.error // result is { error: any, resolved?: undefined, rejected: true }
    }
})(Promise.resolve(1));
```

Also the implementation of `reflectPromise` looks better with `async/await` in my opinion:

```
async function reflectPromise<T>(p: Promise<T>): Promise<
    { data: T, resolved: true, rejected?: undefined } |
    { error: any, resolved?: undefined, rejected: true }
> {
    try {
        return {
            data: await p,
            resolved: true
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            error: e,
            rejected: true
        }
    }
}
```

Without strict null checks, type guard will partially work if we need to change the types a bit, and set both `resolved` and `reject` on both branches:

```
async function reflectPromise<T>(p: Promise<T>): Promise<
    { data: T, resolved: true, rejected: false } |
    { error: any, resolved: false, rejected: true }
> {
    try {
        return {
            data: await p,
            resolved: true,
            rejected: false,
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            error: e,
            rejected: true,
            resolved: false
        }
    }
}

(async function (somePromise: Promise<number>) {
    const result = await (reflectPromise(somePromise));
    const didReject = !!result.rejected
    if (result.rejected) {
        result.error // result is { error: any, resolved?: undefined, rejected: true }
    } 

    if (result.resolved) {
        result.data // result { data: number, resolved: true, rejected?: undefined  } 
    }
})(Promise.resolve(1));
```

Comment: Super super thank you for the explanations here! I'm new to TypeScript so learning a lot. This is super useful I wish I could give you more up vote points!! Especially notes on `void`, and strict null checking, it pointed me to looking into learning those differences now.