# $q.allsettled equivalent in angular 2 to catch all the success and failed

Tags: angular, es6-promise, q

I wanna call a delete api for each selected customer. I am using one service layer.
so when I call the service with the selected custoer code then the customer will be deleted.

In AngularJS I used $.allSettled which will give callbacks for fullfilled and not full filled. I can insert the success and failed customer deletions and I can show in UI about succeeded list and failed list.

```js
 $q.allSettled(promises)
                .then(function(results) {
                    results.forEach(function(result) {
                        if (result.state === 'fulfilled') {
                            // success :)

                          
                        } else {
                            // failed :(

                           //result.reason.config.data contains api input data
                        }
                    });
                }).finally(function() {
                    
                });
```

```js
this.promises = [];
//FORMING LIST OF PROMISES
this.customerList.forEach(code => {
     this.promises.push(this.customersservice.delete(code));
});


Promise.all(this.promises).then(values => { 
  console.log(values);
}).catch(reason => { 
    //here i need to catch every time an api call fails for some reason , so that I can show in UI
  console.log(reason)
});


//SERVICE
 delete(code: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/` + code)
}
```

I implemented but I need to get all the success list as well as failed list. So that I can show in UI. which customers deletion failed and which are get success. I wanna maintain one array contain with objects which are having { custCode:100 , status: fail/success }

How to achieve this in angular2+

Comment: Just use the native `Promise.all([promise, ...])` implementation.

Comment: @Brandon I implemented but I need to get all the success list as well as failed list. So that I can show in UI. which customers deletion failed and which are get success. I wanna maintain one array  contain with objects which are having custCode:100 and status: fail/success.

Comment: See this answer for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises

Comment: @Brandon I will check out. Do I need to change anything in service so that it returns promise, or its fine?

Comment: Yes, your service will need to return a promise, not an observable.

Comment: @Brandon I am able to do this but one thing, I would like to know the payload sent  when calling the promise. So that I can match with the received response and show the colors inside a table ( red, green ) etc

Comment: If you need to keep track of which payload for which promise, you'll probably want to keep a separate object for that so you can compare them later.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, I have that master list but response which is received dont have any information to map to the master data.

Comment: You don't have any unique identifiers in your response you could use to map back to your payload(s) object?

Comment: @Brandon sorry , I didn't understand. Can you please elaborate with an example. Thanks

Comment: @Brandon "You don't have any unique identifiers in your response you could use to map back to your payload(s) object? "  
Ans: To associate request and response I dont have any unique identifier.

Comment: You might need to adjust your request payload and response so you have something to coordinate them on, since there's no guarantee that the promises will complete in a specific order.