# JavaScript How to prevent pushing null in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise, each

I'm working with Promises in Node (also using Mongoose and Lodash) and I need to wait for a list of operations against the database to be ready and push the results to an array:

```
var users = [];

var email_to_id = function(email) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    User.findOne({email: email}).exec().then(function(user, err) {
      if (user) {
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
};

_.each(emails, function(email) {
  users.push(
    email_to_id(email).then(function(user, err) {
      if (user) {
        return user;
      } else {
        // How not to return anything?
      }
    }).catch(next)
  );
});
```

So far so good, however, if I pass a wrong email and `email_to_id` rejects, the `_.each` function will push a `null` to the `users` array.

How to prevent it from pushing `null`? And instead not push anything.

Comment: `.catch(next)` This looks important, what does `next` do?

Comment: Also, I'm *pretty sure* `.then` will ignore its second argument - won't `err` always be `undefined`? (that's what the `.catch` is for)

Comment: `.then(function(user, err) {` that's not a promise - you're also using the [Promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), as `User.findOne({email: email}).exec()` returns a promise, there is no need to wrap it in a new promise

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Don't use `_.each` with promises! Use `map`, and then `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
const reflect = p => p.then(v => ({data: v, status: "fulfilled" }),
                            e => ({data: e, status: "rejected" }));
const emailPromises = emails.map((email)=>email_to_id(email)).map(reflect);

const filterdSuccessPromises = Promise.all(emailPromises)
                                        .then(results=>results
                                                            .filter(x => x.status === "resolved")
                                                            .map(data=>data.data)
                                        ));
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises). It maps all values into objects which says whether it succeeded or not. Then we filter values which succeeded. And you can get the data by using `filterdSuccessPromises.then`

EDIT: Thinking about this you should actually filter/clean invalid emails before you make any calls less expensive, I am not sure why i didn't suggest this first

```
var emails = emails.filter((email)=>email) //or any other validations.
```