# how to prevent promise loop interruption despite errors

Tags: node.js, promise

I just started using `Promise` in my node app. And I believe that in the code below the loop will break if one of then returns an error, which is rejected.

Is there a way to let the loop finish, skipping the ones with errors. And I still would like all the error notices at the end of the loop.

One more question: Is there a better way to `resolve` instead of using `count++; if(count===items.length) resolve(items)`

```
get_customer_purchase = (items) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    let count = 0;
    for (let i in items) {
      get_options(items[i].id).then((options)=>{
        //do some process
         count++; if(count===items.length) resolve (items)
      }).catch((error)=>reject(error))
    }    
  })
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises)

Comment: Look into `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
get_customer_purchase = (items) => {
  const promiseArray = items.map((item) => {
    return get_options(item.id)
  })

  return Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then((optionsResult) => items)
}
```

Notice that if one `get_options` will fail, you will receive a single fail:

```
get_customer_purchase(array)
  .then(items => /** do stuff */ )
  .catch(error => /** one get_options fail */ )
```

If you want to ignore the errors of some `get_options` you could simply change:

```
return get_options(item.id).catch(err => {return null})
```

and then use a `.filter` function in `optionsResult`:

```
.then((optionsResult) => optionsResult.filter(_ => _!==null))
```