# Capture individual record in catch statement if any error occurs while processing data through Promise.all

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I'm processing multiple records using Promise.all now if any error occurs I want to capture individual record in catch statement

I have written a method callApi now I'm calling callApi method in main code

```
try {
 let result = await callApi(res)
}
catch (err) {

}

async function callApi(records) {
  return Promise.all(
    records.map(async record => {
        await processRecord(record)
    })
  )
}
```

I want to display/capture individual record in catch block if any error occurs
ex below

```
try {
 let result = await callApi(res)
}
catch (err) {
 console.log('Got error while processing this record', record)
}
```

But how I will get record variable in catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's `processRecord` that may throw, if you want the record it's processing to be what is caught, rather than the actual error, `catch` the `processRecord` error, and `throw` the record:

```
function callApi(records) {
  return Promise.all(
    records.map(record => (
      processRecord(record)
        .catch((err) => {
          throw record;
        })
    ))
  )
}
```

It may be useful to return both the record and the error when catching, though:

```
try {
  let result = await callApi(res)
} catch ({ err, record }) { // <--------
  console.log('Got error while processing this record', record);
  console.log(err);
}

function callApi(records) {
  return Promise.all(
    records.map(record => (
      processRecord(record)
        .catch((err) => {
          throw { err, record };
        })
    ))
  )
}
```

Note that because `callApi` already explicitly returns a Promise, there's no need to make it an `async` function.

To wait for all requests to finish, and then check the errors on each, do something like:

```
function callApi(records) {
  return Promise.all(
    records.map(record => (
      processRecord(record)
        .then(value => ({ status: 'fulfilled', value }))
        .catch(err => ({ status: 'rejected', reason: { record, err } }))
    ))
  );
}

const result = await callApi(res);
const failures = result.filter(({ status }) => status === 'rejected');
failures.forEach(({ reason: { record, err } }) => {
  // record failed for reason err
});
```

Comment: Interestingly it's not capturing error in catch block if I print result in in try block it's giving all errors and records.

Comment: Oops, that's right, have to actually `throw` for it to be caught in the outer `catch`

Comment: Got it, what if I want print all error records in catch block , it's giving single error record because if error happens it's throwing immediately.

Comment: Use something like [Promise.allSettled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-es6-promises-complete-even-rejected-promises), then filter by the ones with errors

Comment: Can you provide above code with Promise.allSettled

Comment: Ok, see edit (`Promise.allSettled` isn't actually in the spec yet, it's just a proposal)