# How to run concurrent promises in JS and then wait for them to finish without Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I need to do something like:

```
promiseFunction1().then((result) => {

}).catch((err) => {
    // handle err
});

promiseFunction2().then((result) => {

}).catch((err) => {
    // handle err
});

....

promiseFunctionN().then((result) => {

}).catch((err) => {
    // handle err
});

// WAIT FOR BOTH PROMISES TO FINISH
functionWhenAllPromisesFinished();
```

I cannot use `Promise.all`, as I DO NOT CARE IF ONE or ALL OF THEM FAIL. I need to be sure that ALL promises have finished. Also, the callback functions in `then()` are quite unique to each of the `promiseFunctionX()`.

I am sure this is somewhat trivial, but I cannot figure it out. My initial idea was to keep a counter in the upper scope of running promises and incrementing it when one is run and decrementing it in `finally()`. Then I would need some `async function checkIfRunningPromisesAre0()` , but I am not sure how to implement this either, as it looked like recursion hell.

Here is my sample, but consider it just a material to laugh at poor implementation:

```
async function RunningPromisesFinished(){
    if(RunningPromises > 0){
        await sleep(2000);
        return await RunningPromisesFinished();
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

on top of that Id have to implement `async function sleep(N)` and in few seconds the recursion level would be high, which im sure is not good for RAM.

Comment: Promise.all is resolved when all the promises are resolved, that pretty much solves your problem. If you don't want to do something with the exception just let it be!

Comment: `createSomePromise().catch(()=>doSomething())` will ***always*** return a promise that cannot reject (unless you do something stupid in the `catch` handler). This means that your presumption that you can't use `Promise.all` here is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collect all the promises:

```
  const promise1 = promiseFunction1().then((result) => {
   }).catch((err) => {
     // handle err
   });
```

Then you can use `Promise.all` on them:

```
  await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, /*...*/ ]);
```

> I cannot use Promise.all, as I DO NOT CARE IF ONE or ALL OF THEM FAIL

For sure you can. As you added a `.catch` to each promise that gets the promise chain back into the resolution branch, `promise1` will never reject, therefore `Promise.all` will never reject too.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So what would be the results array for item on position of promise that errored and was consumed by its catch()?

Comment: @michnovka whatever you returned from the `.catch` callback.

Comment: @michnovka Interestingly enough, I just saw an article about some v8 updates and there is currently a proposal for a `Promise.allSettled` method that will resolve once all promises have resolved or rejected. [Here's the proposal on Github](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled).

Comment: Until `Promise.allSettled()` is fully implemented, [here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/3478010).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) method:

> The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after
> all of the given promises have either resolved or rejected, with an
> array of objects that each describe the outcome of each promise.

As this is relatively new, it might not be supported by the majority of browsers yet. Here is a polyfill:

```
 function allSettled(promises) {
    let wrappedPromises = promises.map(p => 
      Promise.resolve(p)
        .then(
           val => ({ status: 'fulfilled', value: val }),
           err => ({ status: 'rejected', reason: err })
        )
    );
    return Promise.all(wrappedPromises);
 }
```

Comment: Yes I do. But I dont think this is supported in node 10.

Comment: @michnovka i add polyfill