# Is there any symbol for Promise status?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-next

Since there is a [new Promise combinator](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators#promise.allsettled) called `Promise.allSettled` I am interested in performing some code logic based on the status of the resolution of Promises.

eg:

```
Promise.allSettled([
    callApi("http://example.com/wishlist"),
    callApi("http://example.com/brands")
])
.then(([wishlist, brands]) => {
    if(brands.status === "failed"){
        notifyMe()
    }
})
```

As you can see I am using a static value to compare the resolution status of promises `brands.status === "failed"`

You can call me paranoid, but how JavaScript is evolving this value might change in the future and I would prefer to have something less static.

My question is: Is there any `Symbol.PromiseRejected|Symbol.PromiseResolved` or something relevant that encapsulates the promise resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can call me paranoid, but how JavaScript is evolving this value might change in the future

No, it won't. JS will (need to) stay backwards-compatible, this will never change. There's no reason to rename the `.status` property either, it's not like the property names of result objects like this (or iterator result objects etc) would collide with anything new.

> My question is: Is there any `Symbol.PromiseRejected|Symbol.PromiseResolved` or something relevant that encapsulates the promise resolution?

No, there's not. They're not symbols anyway.

If you're absolutely paranoid, you can either [write your own trivial `allSettled` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/1048572) where you can control the shape of the result objects, or you can write `isRejected(result)` and `isFulfilled(result)` helper functions to call everywhere so that in the unlikely event of something changing you would need to change only a single line of code.