# Ignoring failed promises in Promoise.all

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch

I am fetching URLs specified in the array and then combine fetched results. 
I want to ignore failed fetches.

While are tons of post on the subject:

1. [Wait until all promises complete even if some rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected#answer-31424853)
2. https://gist.github.com/nhagen/a1d36b39977822c224b8

I just can't figure our how to apply this to my code, that fetches URLs from the array:

```
    Promise.all (arrayOfBlobs.map (x => fetch (x).then (response => response.json())) )         
    .then (json => {
                json.forEach ( x => { 
                    if (Array.isArray (x)) {
                        // this json has array of objects
                        console.log (`Received ${x.length} prospects`)
                        x.forEach ( y => combinedArray.push (y) )   
                    }   
                    else {
                        // this json has single prospect object
                        console.log (`Received single prospect`)
                        combinedArray.push (x)
                    }
                })
        this.setState({loadingTable: false, data: combinedArray})
    })  
    .catch (error => {
        console.error (error.message)
        this.setState({loadingTable: false, data: combinedArray})
    })
```

For example below did not work:

```
Promise.all (arrayOfBlobs.map (x => fetch (x).then (response => response.json())) )         
            .then (json => {
                        json.forEach ( x => { 
                            if (Array.isArray (x)) {
                                // this json has array of objects
                                console.log (`Received ${x.length} prospects`)
                                x.forEach ( y => combinedArray.push (y) )   
                            }   
                            else {
                                // this json has single prospect object
                                console.log (`Received single prospect`)
                                combinedArray.push (x)
                            }
                        })
                        .catch (e => {console.log (`Failed to fetch due to ${e.message}`)})
                this.setState({loadingTable: false, data: combinedArray})
            })  
            .catch (error => {
                console.error (error.message)
                this.setState({loadingTable: false, data: combinedArray})
            })
```

What do I need to do to modified my code so failed fetches are ignored?

Comment: Try something like `fetch (x).then(response => response.json()).catch(() => "mark as failed")` and filter afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `catch` is supposed to go on the individual `fetch` promise inside the `map`:

```
Promise.all(arrayOfBlobs.map(x =>
    fetch(x)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(e => {
//  ^^^^^^^
        console.log(`Failed to fetch due to ${e.message}`);
        return null; // this value will get into the `json` array
    })
))         
.then(json => {
    const combinedArray = [];
    for (const x in json) { 
        if (Array.isArray(x)) {
            // this json has array of objects
            console.log (`Received ${x.length} prospects`)
            combinedArray.push(...x);
        } else if (x != null) {
            // this json has single prospect object
            console.log (`Received single prospect`)
            combinedArray.push(x)
        } else { // x == null
            console.log(`(ignored error)`)
        })
    }
    this.setState({loadingTable: false, data: combinedArray})
})
```

Also [don't forget to handle http (status code) errors](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)!

Comment: Yes, it did work! I actually tried it to, however the result was not what I have expected, hence I thought I was wrong.

This approach put "undefined" into the combined array. Yes, I can filter array and remove undefined values. 

However I was hopping for a more elegant solution: when promise failed, it's results are completely ignored and are not added to the combined array.

I suspect I do need to filter promises and reject failed promises, as pointed our for this to work.

but I guess filtering array is easier.

Comment: There's no way to do it without filtering the result, neither with `Promise.all` nor with `Promise.allSettled`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Promise.allSettled()` it will return that status of fulfilled/rejected with the value.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: This rocks! Thanks you both: Matt and Begri. I can now see how to make either of this work

Answer (score 0):

A version of Promise.allSettled that removes rejected results:

```
function allFullfilled(promises) {

  const responses = [];
  let settledCount = 0;

  return new Promise(res => {

    for(const promise of promises) {

      promise
        .then( promiseResult => {
          responses.push(promiseResult);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // ignore
        })
        .then( () => {
          settledCount++;
          if (settledCount === promises.length) {
            res(responses);
          }
        });
    }

  });

}
```

Comment: Here is what I did to handle only un-rejected promises with real values:
if ( ( typeof (x.value) !== "undefined") && (x.status !== "rejected") ) {