# Conditionally execute functions that have callbacks each returning values when triggered

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, callback, async.js

I have an array that looks like this :

```
"attributes": [{"id": "5dad5242e7038210842ec59c","value": 3},{"id": "5dbade6a824f3e2244b2870b","value": 6},{"id": "5d7c943a5759f91e187520cc","value": 17}]
```

Each value in the array corresponds to a schema from where I will fetch that data. 
Ex : `if(value == 1){ fetch data from schemaA}`

Based on the data fetched from each schema I will repopulate the array with additional information, so at the end the array would look like this:

```
"attributes": [{"id": "5dad5242e7038210842ec59c","value": 3, "name": "attributeA"},{"id": "5dbade6a824f3e2244b2870b","value": 6, "name": "attributeF"},{"id": "5d7c943a5759f91e187520cc","value": 17, "name": "attributeQ"}]
```

So far I have written a function :

```
exports.fetchAttributes = (attr, callback) => {
    try {
        switch (attr.value) {
            case 3:
                this.fetchAttributeC(attr.id, (err, attributeB) => {
                    callback(err, attributeB);
                });
                break;
            case 6:
                this.fetchAttributeF(attr.id, (err, attributeF) => {
                    callback(err, attributeF);
                });
                break;
            case 7:
                this.fetchAttributeQ(attr.id, (err, attributeQ) => {
                    callback(err, attributeQ);
                });
                break;
            default : console.log("Invalid value");
        }
    } catch(e){
        console.log("Catch in fetchAttributes "+e);
        return callback(e, null);
    }
}
```

The above function is being called within another function:

```
exports.functionAttributes = (attributes, callback) => {
    let newAttributes = [];
    attributes.forEach((attr) => {
        this.fetchAttributes(attr, (err, attributeFull) => {
           newAttributes.push(attributeFull);
        })
    }
   //need to pass in callback here, but obviously there is a scope issue
}
```

I need this array with newAttributes as I have to pass it to the final callback in async waterfall where this function is. Due to the scope issue newAttributes is always empty. I need help finding a better way to achieve this. So I can finally end up with result array as I have shown above. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S : I have tried conditional callbacks, promises but I couldn't make it work as I need to pass parameters in each step. Feel free to point out where I am wrong, or if there is a better method of achieving this, I would be happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [promise list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would perfectly solve your problem as long as you structured it correctly.

**First:** Make fetchAttributes return a promise:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ...Your try catch using resolve() and reject()
})
```

**Second:** Create the Array of your promises

```
let fetchList= [];
attributes.forEach((attr) => {
    fetchList.push(...your function)
}
```

**Third:** If you don't care whether one fails, make sure to add in a reflection so the promise.all() always completes -> [Check this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected)

**Finally** Once your promise.all() resolves, you can loop through all of the returned values and push them to the newAttributes variable!!!

If you have trouble with it I can provide more info but that should get you started!