# Catch all rejections from promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]

const wrapper = (task) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   if(task !== 1) {
    console.log('Rejected task -', task)
    reject(task)
   }
   else {
    console.log('Resolved task -', task)
    resolve(task)
   }
  }, 1000 * task)
 })
}
const main = async() => {
 try{
  await Promise.all(array.map(async task => 
    wrapper(task)
  ))
 } catch(e){
  console.log('Main function catch error from task -', e)
 }
}

main()
```

Following this code, just **task1** will be resolved and for other **task2** and **task3**, these will be rejected with task number. But at main function, rejection will be caught once.

**Current Output:**

```
Resolved task - 1
Rejected task - 2
Main function catch error from task - 2
Rejected task - 3
```

**Expect Output:**

```
Resolved task - 1
Rejected task - 2
Main function catch error from task - 2
Rejected task - 3
Main function catch error from task - 3
```

Is there anyway to catch all the rejection? Using **for loop** is not a solution. Since it will  run the task asynchronously but I'd like to run the tasks synchronously like multiple threading.

Comment: Especially have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56255129/906113).

Comment: Just move the `catch` inside the `map` loop, so that you're able to catch all errors individually?