# JavaScript call multiple async calls parallel

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an array called `imagesToUpload`. Uploading function returns a promise. Right now I have to wait, images upload by one after another. This is my sample code.

```js
function uploadTos3Bucket(filename){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(filename+'.png')
    })
}

const imagesToUpload = ['Homer','Bart','Lisa','Millhouse'];

async function controller() {
    const links = []

    for (const imageFile of imagesToUpload) {
        const link = await uploadTos3Bucket(imageFile);
        links.push(link)
    }
    console.log('links',links)
    
}
controller();
```

Instead of this I want something where I pass the images array. Images upload parallel. Once all finished I get the links array. Of-cause I know the concept of `Promise.all()`

**This is not what I want.**

```
const [image1,image2] = await Promise.all([uploadTos3Bucket('Homer'),uploadTos3Bucket('Bart')])
```

I don't want assign to so many variables. I just want an array with all the links and most importantly if some image failed to upload, it should ignore and not break the entire process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `imagesToUpload` array, use `.map` to transform it into an array of Promises, then call `Promise.allSettled` on that array, filter for only the fulfilled promises by checking the `status` property of each resulting object, and finally `.map` to their resolve values:

```js
function uploadTos3Bucket(filename){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(filename+'.png')
    })
}

const imagesToUpload = ['Homer','Bart','Lisa','Millhouse'];

async function controller() {
  const results = await Promise.allSettled(imagesToUpload.map(uploadTos3Bucket));
  const links = results
    .filter(({ status }) => status === 'fulfilled')
    .map(({ value }) => value);
  console.log('links',links)  
}
controller();
```

For browsers that don't recognize `Promise.allSettled` yet, add a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled), or implement the functionality with one of the many methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561).

Comment: A standard `Promise` no longer exposes a `status` property.

Comment: No, but `Promise.allSettled` resolves to an array of objects which *do* have that property - press "Run code snippet" (on Chrome, FF, Safari, or Node) to see it working

Comment: oops, yes - I hadn't noticed your use of `allSettled`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this works! Thanks a lot. But will this improve the performance level. I tried this with my old one using console.timeEnd() seems this new one take more time?

Comment: @PathumKalhan It shouldn't - this will run in parallel. In contrast, your original code `await`s each Promise in serial, which should take *much* longer than the parallel method

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't check it with the actual s3upload function. May be this will work with that. Anyways Thanks a lot. =)