# How to call a method multiple times (dynamically) in asynchronous way in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am writing a script in node.js where I have method with a single parameter - id.

```
funcToCall(id)
{
    // some code ...

    returns a promise
}

var ids = [ list of ids] // input occurs dynamically
```

I will get a list of id's as input and I need to call the method with each input id in an asynchronous way. I have found a way to [handle Promise.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/9723876) for the static/fixed number of method calls

```
const reflect = p => p.then(v => ({v, status: "fulfilled" }),
                        e => ({e, status: "rejected" }));

var arr = [ fun(id1), fun(id2), fun(id3) ];      // how to make this dynamically ?

Promise.all(arr.map(reflect)).then(function(results) {
    var success = results.filter(x => x.status === "fulfilled");
});
```

Is there any possible way to dynamically call the method multiples times and in an asynchronous way?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does "dynamically call the method multiples times and in an asynchronous way" mean?  I don't understand what problem you need to solve with your existing code based on `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.map` on arrays and use `Promise.all` like this

```
function funcToCall(id) {
  return Promise.resolve(id); // this could be your promise.
}

const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Promise.all(ids.map(id => funcToCall(id))).then((res = console.log(res)));
```