# passing async functions to promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I know `promise.all()` expects an array of promises. 
But, is it possible to do something like below? If no, please suggest a workaround.

It's not recommended to use `await` inside `for` loop. That's why I am pushing in an array and doing `promise.all()` on that.

```
var functionArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i += 1) {
  ...
  if (params.origins !== '' && params.destinations !== '') {
    functionArray.push(async function() {
      response = await getDistance(params.origins, params.destinations);
      if (response.error) {
        // handle error
        return null
      } else {
        distances = response.data.rows[0].elements.map((el, index) => {
          el.emp_id = empIdOrder[index];
          return el;
        });
        sortedDistances = sortDistance(distances);
        return formatDataForInsert(jobs[i].job_id, sortedDistances);
      }
    });
  }
}
var dataToBeinserted = await Promise.all(functionArray); // return an array with results
```

It doesn't work as expected. 
`await Promise.all(functionArray);` always return `[ [AsyncFunction], [AsyncFunction] ]`. 
Shouldn't it be resolved instead?

Comment: _"It's not recommended to use await inside for loop"_  got a reference for that?

Comment: @Phil `jshint` and `eslint` both suggests. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for clarifying. I only ask as using `await` within a `for` loop does actually work (as opposed to within a `forEach` callback). Of course, as the link says, its sequential and loses out on potential parallel operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that `Promise.all` accepts an array of *promises*, not an array of functions - your current code won't work.

The main issue is that you're only *conditionally* using the result of the asynchronous operation. You can chain `.then` onto a Promise to make the Promise resolve to the result of the `.then`, rather than its initial resolve value. That is:

```
Promise.resolve(2)
  .then(res => res + 4)
```

results in a Promise that resolves to 6.

Using this logic, you can push a Promise to the array which, in its `then`, conditionally works with the result (`distances = response.data...`) and returns the final value, *or* doesn't return anything. At the end, call `Promise.all` on the array of Promises, and filter by boolean:

```
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i += 1) {
  if (params.origins !== '' && params.destinations !== '') {
    promises.push(
      getDistance(params.origins, params.destinations)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.error) {
            // handle error
            return null
          } else {
            const distances = response.data.rows[0].elements.map((el, index) => {
              el.emp_id = empIdOrder[index];
              return el;
            });
            const sortedDistances = sortDistance(distances);
            return formatDataForInsert(jobs[i].job_id, sortedDistances);
          }
      })
    );
    }
}
const results = await Promise.all(promises)
  .filter(Boolean); // filter out failures

var dataToBeinserted = await Promise.all(functionArray); // return an array with results
```

Comment: It it rejects, the `Promise.all` will reject. If it may reject, and you want to just ignore the rejection but process those which succeed, use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56255129) and filter out the promises which rejected.

Comment: `formatDataForInsert(jobs[i].job_id, sortedDistances);` returns `[ {...}, {....}...]`; `result` should be `[{..}, {...}..]` not `[[{...}, {..}..], [{...}, {...}..]...]` Can I spread it, somehow?

Comment: You can flatten it afterwards: `.filter(Boolean).flat()`

Comment: Had to  wrap in parenthesis   `(await Promise.all(promises)).filter(Boolean).flat();` , otherwise getting error  `Promise.all(...).filter is not a function`.

Comment: Oh right, need the `await` to resolve the `Promise.all` first

Answer (score 1):

The function in your example is never executed, in order for them to resolve you can do like this (wrap it in parentheses and call right away):

```
functionArray.push((async function() {
  response = await getDistance(params.origins, params.destinations);
  if (response.error) {
    // handle error
    return null
  } else {
    distances = response.data.rows[0].elements.map((el, index) => {
      el.emp_id = empIdOrder[index];
      return el;
    });
    sortedDistances = sortDistance(distances);
    return formatDataForInsert(jobs[i].job_id, sortedDistances);
  }
})());
```

Or:

```
Promise.all(fnArray.map(f => f())
```

Comment: Can you explain? Does `Promise.all()` runs anything passed parallel or it works that way only with promises? It clearly says it expects promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all .

Comment: @Sujeet: The example in your link suggests otherwise: `const promise2 = 42;`

Comment: Yes, I got to know this now _when the iterable contains no promises or when the iterable contains promises that have been fulfilled and non-promises that have been returned_  reference is the same as above.

Comment: So, yeah we can pass a function as well, and promise will be resolved if it returns successfully or will be rejected if that function has caught an error inside it using try/catch/throw blocks.  learned a lot about promises here :)

Answer (score 1):

You should push Promise object to the array.
so just wrap the async function with Promise.