# Can not access outer scope variable inside chained promise used in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I need to do `async/await` inside `for..loop`, but that way I can't do parallel operations. 
So I am pushing those promises into an variable `promises` later I will do `promise.all()` on it.
Here is my code.

```
const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < todayAssignedJobs.length; i += 1) {
    promises.push(Leaderboard.findOrCreate({...}).then((leaderboard, created) => {
      if (!created) {
        const rating = (todayAssignedJobs[i].rating + leaderboard.rating * leaderboard.jobs_completed) / (leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1);
        const commission = todayAssignedJobs[i].commission + leaderboard.commission;
        const jobsCompleted = leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1;
        Leaderboard.update({
          rating,
          commission,
          jobs_completed: jobsCompleted,
          updated_by: 'system',
        }, {
          where: {
            id: leaderboard.id,
          },
        });
      }
      AssignedJob.update({
        is_leaderboard_generated: true,
      }, {
        where: {
          id: todayAssignedJobs[i].id,
        },
      });
    }));
  }
await Promise.all(promises)
```

Somehow, I am unable to get the id when I do `Assigned.update({..}, { where: { id: todayAssignedJobs[i].id }})`

Getting error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value

Can someone explain what is going on? Also, please suggest can I do below?

```
promises.push(async () => { // I will use await here })
```

Comment: I would log the value of `todayAssignedJobs[i]`. My guess is that the object doesn't have an `id` property, since a for loop using `let` provides proper lexical scope for `i`, so asynchronicity isn't the problem. For a cleaner approach, notice you're basically re-implementing [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), so just use that instead of a `for` loop to initialize `promises`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for your suggestion. I replaced `for` with `map` now it's much cleaner. :)

Comment: A `then` callback takes only a single parameter, `(leaderboard, created)` does not make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some further improvements on the existing answer.

`Leaderboard.update()` and `AssignedJob.update()` are async functions that need to be awaited, so the callback function needs to be converted to an `async` function. This ensures that the promise doesn't resolve until all the database operations are completed, not just the `findOrCreate()`:

```
const promises = todayAssignedJobs.map(async todayAssigned => {
  const [leaderboard, created] = await Leaderboard.findOrCreate({...});

  if (!created) {
    const rating = (todayAssigned.rating + leaderboard.rating * leaderboard.jobs_completed) / (leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1);
    const commission = todayAssigned.commission + leaderboard.commission;
    const jobsCompleted = leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1;

    await Leaderboard.update({
      rating,
      commission,
      jobs_completed: jobsCompleted,
      updated_by: 'system',
    }, {
      where: {
        id: leaderboard.id,
      },
    });
  }

  await AssignedJob.update({
    is_leaderboard_generated: true,
  }, {
    where: {
      id: todayAssigned.id,
    },
  });
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

A more fundamental problem with this approach is that `Leaderboard.findOrCreate()` and `Leaderboard.update()` are not part of a single transaction. This is problematic because the `update()` depends on the current value of the entry in `leaderboard`, which creates a race condition in your database due to the [non-atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) modification of the entry:

```
const rating = (todayAssigned.rating + leaderboard.rating * leaderboard.jobs_completed) / (leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1);
const commission = todayAssigned.commission + leaderboard.commission;
const jobsCompleted = leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1;
```

Each of the methods needs to be marked as part of a single transaction. With sequelize.js you can achieve that using a [managed transaction](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/transactions.html):

```
const promises = todayAssignedJobs.map(
  todayAssigned => sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
    const [leaderboard, created] = await Leaderboard.findOrCreate({
      transaction,
      ...
    });

    if (!created) {
      const rating = (todayAssigned.rating + leaderboard.rating * leaderboard.jobs_completed) / (leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1);
      const commission = todayAssigned.commission + leaderboard.commission;
      const jobsCompleted = leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1;

      await Leaderboard.update({
        rating,
        commission,
        jobs_completed: jobsCompleted,
        updated_by: 'system',
      }, {
        transaction,
        where: {
          id: leaderboard.id,
        },
      });
    }

    await AssignedJob.update({
      is_leaderboard_generated: true,
    }, {
      transaction,
      where: {
        id: todayAssigned.id,
      },
    })
  })
);

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: I tried something same, but `promises` was returning an array `[ [AsyncFunction], [AsyncFunction] ]` after calling `await Promise.all(promises)` . Can you explain how `Promise.all(promises)` resolves them here?

Comment: Got it, but  I am not talking about this problem here. Please look here. I tried the same approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337600/passing-async-functions-to-promise-all/61337736

Comment: That's not the same at all, and your question has already been thoroughly answered by someone else.

Comment: But this line _The first problem is that Promise.all accepts an array of promises, not an array of functions - your current code won't work._ aren't we doing the same here? Passing an array of functions to `Promise.all()`

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari by your logic, `let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(v => v * 2)` would make `x` an array of functions. `promises` is an array of _promises_, not functions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that `findOrCreate()` returns an array with two values `[ {...}, boolean ]` 
I was passing them `(leaderboard, created)` here `created` was always `undefined` and `leaderboard` an `array`.
I made changes and now it's working fine.

```
const promises = todayAssignedJobs.map((todayAssigned) => Leaderboard.findOrCreate({...}).then(([leaderboard, created]) => {
    if (!created) {
      const rating = (todayAssigned.rating + leaderboard.rating * leaderboard.jobs_completed) / (leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1);
      const commission = todayAssigned.commission + leaderboard.commission;
      const jobsCompleted = leaderboard.jobs_completed + 1;
      Leaderboard.update({
        rating,
        commission,
        jobs_completed: jobsCompleted,
        updated_by: 'system',
      }, {
        where: {
          id: leaderboard.id,
        },
      });
    }
    AssignedJob.update({
      is_leaderboard_generated: true,
    }, {
      where: {
        id: todayAssigned.id,
      },
    });
  }));

await Promise.all(promises);
```