# Wait for first Promise resolved or all rejected

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to resolve my promise when the first ajax call is successfull and return true, otherwise i need to wait for all rejected promises before return false.

Can I do it with promise.race, allSettled or similars?

Comment: try `promise.all()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until all promises complete even if some rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected)

Comment: @user9879287 `Posmise.all()`  waits for all Promises to be resolved or rejects immediately when one of them is rejected. That is the opposite of what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You look for [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any):

> [...]as soon as one of the promises in the iterable fulfils, returns a single promise that resolves with the value from that promise. If no promises in the iterable fulfil (if all of the given promises are rejected), then the returned promise is rejected with an AggregateError[...]

But it is still experimental, but you could check for existing [polyfills](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-any/issues/6) (I haven't checked that one for correctness, but on the first look it seems valid):

```js
function any(promises) {
  return Promise.all(
    promises.map(promise =>
      promise.then(val => {
        throw val;
      }, reason => reason),
    ),
  ).then(reasons => {
    throw reasons;
  }, firstResolved => firstResolved);
};
```