# Do not fail whole task even if one of promises rejected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux, redux-saga

In redux saga if we want to handle multiple promises, we can use `all` (which is equivalent of `Promise.all`):

```
yield all(
   users.map((user) => call(signUser, user)),
);

function* signUser() {
   yield call(someApi);
   yield put(someSuccessAction);
}
```

**The problem is**, even if one of the promises (calls) fail, the whole task is cancelled.

My goal is to keep the task **alive**, even if one of the promises failed.

In pure JS I could handle it with `Promise.allSettled`, but whats the proper way to do it in redux saga?

**Edit**: still didnt find any suitable solution, even if I wrap the `yield all` in `try... catch` block, still if even one of the calls failed, whole task is canceled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until all promises complete even if some rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks! But Im looking for a specified solution for redux saga

Comment: The principle will be the same even if the syntax differs slightly.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Not really, sagas are held on generators

Comment: Patrickkx, what does that mean, can you give me a reference?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220587/discussion-between-roamer-1888-and-patrickkx).

Comment: You can wrap `all` with try/catch block

Comment: @AlekseyL. still cancels whole task if even one promise rejected

Comment: @Patrickkx, how did you wrapped yield all with try catch?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto like Aleksey recommended

Comment: sorry, let me be more clear. Did you add try/catch involving `yield all` or `call(signUser, user)`

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Just wrapped whole yield all in try catch

Comment: @Patrickkx Please edit this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/all-effect-st344?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fsagas%2Findex.js&theme=dark) so I'll be able to reproduce the issue. Currently try/catch works as expected. There must be some missing details here

Comment: Your question is very nice, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you should change your array of Promises to the `all` method of Redux-Saga, you should write it like below:

```js
yield all(
  users.map((item) =>
    (function* () {
      try {
        return yield call(signUser, item);
      } catch (e) {
        return e; // **
      }
    })()
  )
);
```

You pass a self-invoking generator function with handling the error and instead of `throw` use `return`. hence, the line with two stars(**).

By using this way all of your async actions return as resolved and the `all` method never seen rejection.

Comment: Dear @Patrickkx, I change whole the answer and use another way.

Comment: You could define and use `call` wrapper instead of self-invoking generator. A bit cleaner https://codesandbox.io/s/all-effect-st344?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&module=/src/sagas/index.js&theme=dark&file=/src/sagas/index.js

Comment: Dear @AlekseyL. , Thanks for your lovely comment, even I check the CodeSandBox and I think your code is a little hight level than mine, thanks a lot, but I prefer to have my answer, for appreciate I leave some upvotes to your current correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it by yourself. There is a [PR](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/2160). See below example:

```js
import { all, put, call, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { createStoreWithSaga } from '../../utils';

const someSuccessAction = { type: 'SIGN_USER_SUCCESS' };

function someApi(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (user < 5) {
        resolve('success');
      } else {
        reject('failed');
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const allSettled = (effects) =>
  all(
    effects.map((effect) =>
      call(function* settle() {
        try {
          return { error: false, result: yield effect };
        } catch (err) {
          return { error: true, result: err };
        }
      }),
    ),
  );

function* batchSignUser(action) {
  const r = yield allSettled(action.payload.users.map((user) => call(signUser, user)));
  console.log(r);
}

function* signUser(user) {
  const r = yield call(someApi, user);
  yield put(someSuccessAction);
  return r;
}

function* watchBatchSignUser() {
  yield takeLatest('SIGN_USER', batchSignUser);
}
const store = createStoreWithSaga(watchBatchSignUser);

const users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
store.dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_USER', payload: { users } });
```

The execution result:

```
[
  { error: false, result: 'success' },
  { error: false, result: 'success' },
  { error: false, result: 'success' },
  { error: false, result: 'success' },
  { error: true, result: 'failed' },
  { error: true, result: 'failed' },
  { error: true, result: 'failed' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it the old school way [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)!

```
const promises = [];
users.map((user) => promises.push(call(signUser, user)));


function* signUser() {
  let responses = [];
  responses = yield(yield Promise.allSettled(promises)));
  // filter the onces which are successfull unsuccessfull once don't have value
  responses = responses.filter(response => response.value);
}
```