# PUT action after successful action channel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I have a saga:

```
function* saga1() {
    yield fork(saga2);
    yield all(
        users.map((user) => put('action1', user))
    );

    console.log('finished'); // ---> gets logged immediately, doesnt wait for saga2
}

function* saga2() {
   const channel = yield actionChannel('action1');
   while (true) {
      const r = yield take(channel);
      yield call(api, r);
   }
}
```

**Question**: is there a way to PUT some action **AFTER** every call from `saga2` finished? So I am able to dispatch action or anything **AFTER** channel from saga2 finished?

Comment: But currently (at least in provided sample) channel is never finished (closed)

Comment: @AlekseyL. how to close it then?

Comment: Generally it is `channel.close()`. But from above example it is not clear what are you trying to do. Why do you need the channel here (and not just calling sagas directly)?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Because I want all calls to run in sequence, not parallel

Comment: So run them in sequence How is this related?

Comment: You've asked this in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647621/1113002