# How to wait until all of Promise are fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-firestore, promise, es6-promise

My goal is to get the data from the field with a `reference` data type in a Firestore document. I use nested promise to get the data. The current code did not wait until all of the Promises are fulfilled.

How to make `results.push( object )` wait until all of Promise is fulfilled?

expected results

```
data = {
  createdDate,
  expectedDate,
  customer_name = "John", // name from a document in `customer` collection.
  user_name = "Sherly", // name from a document in `user` collection.
}
```

actual results, the customer_name is "" instead of "John" which is fetched from a document in `customer` collection.

```
data = {
  createdDate,
  expectedDate,
  customer_name = "",
  user_name = "",
}
```

```
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("sales_order")
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      let results = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        let data = doc.data();
        console.log(data);
        const createdDate = data.createdDate.seconds;
        // const deliveryDate = data.deliveryDate ? data.deliveryDate.seconds : null;
        const expectedDate = data.expectedDate.seconds;

        let customer_name = "";
        data.customer.get().then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            const { name } = doc.data();
            customer_name = name;
          }
        })

        let user_name = "";
        data.user.get().then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            const { name } = doc.data();
            console.log(name);
            user_name = name;
          }
        })

        results.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: {
            createdDate,
            // deliveryDate,
            expectedDate,
            customer_name,
            user_name,
            // total,
            // invoiceStatus,
          },
        });
      });

      return results;
    })
```

edit:
Reference: [Basic knowledge to understand Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected)

A community member suggested me to look up on the reference links and it does help you understand better more about Promise. Mr. trincot's answer is exactly what I am looking for although without the reference links, I could not understand how Promise works.

I appreciate both the anonymous community member and Mr. trincot to give me insight on how Promise works.

Comment: Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: First result when googling the question title: [Wait until all promises complete even if some rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected)

Comment: If you just interesting in fulfilled - Promise.all() when all promises resolved, or Promise.allSettled() when doesn't matter - resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the inner part of your loop, you could either chain the `then` calls and call `push` in the final `then` callback, or, you could combine the promises from two `.get()` lookups  in a `Promise.all` argument.

The outer loop should return a list of promises, which you then can feed to a `Promise.all` too. I would suggest to replace the `forEach` loop with a `docs.map` loop, which can return those promises.

There is then no need to call `push`. The `map` call will create the array:

```
Promise.all(firebase.firestore().collection("sales_order").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    return querySnapshot.docs.map(function (doc) {
        let data = doc.data();
        return Promise.all([data.customer.get(), data.user.get()]).then(function (docs) {
            return docs.map(doc => doc.exists ? doc.data().name : "");
        }).then(function ([customer_name, user_name]) { 
            return {
                id: doc.id,
                data: {
                    createdDate: data.createdDate.seconds,
                    expectedDate: data.expectedDate.seconds,
                    customer_name,
                    user_name,
                },
            };
        });
    });
})).then(function (results) {
    // deal with results here
});
```

Comment: The return value from `Promise.all( [ ] )` is an array. I did a little revision to the return value from `doc.exists ? doc.data().name : ""` to `[doc[0].data().name, doc[1].data().name]`. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, corrected. I kept the doc.exists-check though.