# React Query - fire function once when all requests have been finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm looking for a solution on how to fire function when all requests have been finished.

I'm using React Query to manage external data state and `useMutation` hook because I need to re-fetch data on select change.

```
const fetcher1 = async () => await axios.get('XXX');
const fetcher2 = async () => await axios.get('XXX');

const { data, isLoading, mutate: fetchData1 } = useMutation(fetcher1)
const { data2, isLoading: isLoading2, mutate: fetchData2 } = useMutation(fetcher2)

function runWhenReady() {
 console.log("Ready!")
}

// re-fetch on select change and initial fetch
useEffect(() => {
 fetchData1();
 fetchData2();
}, [selectValueChanged])
```

I want to watch for request state change and fire `runWhenReady()` when all of the requests are not pending. I suppose I need to wait for e.g 1s to make a decision.

Could anyone help me with preparing utility to monitor request states?
Thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424561/wait-until-all-promises-complete-even-if-some-rejected

Answer (score 2):

You can look at isSuccess to see when a successful request has happend.

```
const { data, isLoading, mutate: fetchData1, isSuccess: 1isSuccess } = useMutation(fetcher1)
const { data2, isLoading: isLoading2, mutate: fetchData2, isSuccess: 2isSuccess } = useMutation(fetcher2)


useEffect(() => {
  if(1isSuccess && 2isSuccess){
    runWhenReady();
  }
}, [1isSuccess, 2isSuccess]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`mutateAsync` and [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is likely what you are looking for, because `mutateAsync` returns a normal promise that you can chain together. Be aware that you have to catch errors yourselves or you'll see unhandled promise rejections.

```
const { data, isLoading, mutateAsync: fetchData1, isSuccess: 1isSuccess } = useMutation(fetcher1)
const { data2, isLoading: isLoading2, mutateAsync: fetchData2, isSuccess: 2isSuccess } = useMutation(fetcher2)

<button onClick={() => {
    Promise.allSettled([fetchData1(), fetchData2()])
        .then(results => runWhenReady())
        .catch(...)
} />
```