# Angular 2 - multiple HTTP POST request : handle error from each request

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way where in i can post multiple HTTP POST requests and just in case there is error on one or more of them then i can know which of those got the error.

I tried implementing many logic via observables but no success. Please suggest.

Comment: Please add more details such as the code that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You could use Promises

```
for all requestItems {
    http.post(url, body).toPromise().catch(error => {
       // This request failed.
    })
}
```

or if you want to wait for all to finish, you can collect the promises to an array and then use

```
Promise.all(promises)
    .catch(error => ...)
    .then(results => ...);
```

as can be seen in [Handling errors in Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362733/handling-errors-in-promise-all)

**Edit:**

You can use Promise.all this way:

```
// Create an array of your promises
const promises = [...];
const resolvedPromises = [];
promises.forEach(promise => {
    // Collect resolved promises - you may return some values from then and catch
    resolvedPromises.push(promise
        .then(result => 'OK')
        .catch(error => 'Error')
    );
});
Promise.all(resolvedPromises).then(results => {
    // results contains values returned from then/catch before
    console.log('Finished');
})
```

Comment: If you want to know which request threw exception catch them on individual promise level. Promise.all() will catch only the first one (all or nothing attitude).

Comment: I can't catch errors on individual promise level, because i need to wait for all promises to finish and then find out which all errored out. Promise.all won't help either.

Comment: I added an example of Promise.all() usage.

Comment: @mansi have you tried the code I added? If it helped, please mark the answer as accepted, if not, let me know what's the problem with it.