# what is the canonical way to prevent Promise.all from rejecting on first error?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following code

```
await doAllCats();
await doAllDogs();
console.log("Finished processing Cats and Dogs ")

function doAllCats() {
  let promiseArray = [];
  for(let cat of cats) {
    promiseArray.push(doOneCat(cat));
  }
  return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}
function doOneCat(cat) {
  let promise = doSomeAsyncStuffWithACat(cat);
  promise.catch((err)=> {
    console.error("there was a problem with "+cat+" but processing should continue as normal for the other cats and dogs");
  })
  return promise; 
}
```

which is working fine when all Cats and Dogs succeed. However, sometimes a cat will fail, and when that happens, I get an exception at the topmost level. The code that deals with a cat failing is inside `doOneCat` and that is performing correctly. However, the failed promise is still in the `promiseArray` and so I get a premature "finished".

What is the simplest/canonical method of preventing `Promise.all` rejecting on the first exception?

Comment: You can check this answer that may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378082/4409060

Comment: But why? The whole point behind Promise.all() is only move along when all have resolved. If any reject, they all reject. That's the design.

Comment: @randy well it depends. There are legit usecases for both cases (and both can easily be solved using `Promise.all`). (e.g. batching unrelated database operations, if one fails the others still can go on).

Comment: @Jonas - it is a codesmell and misuse of `Promise.all()` - https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all

Comment: @RandyCasburn if Promise.all is the wrong tool with which to await the completion (regardless of outcome) of an array of async functions, then I'm happy to hear your suggestion for an alternative approach.

Comment: @randy who said that? You just quoted the spec which says how Promise.all behaves, not how it should be used.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Is there a better native alternative? I'm not a promise expert, but I'm not sure I agree that it's bad semantics: if you're passing a Promise from `.catch` and that `.catch` resolver doesn't raise an error, then the Promise provided to `.all` has the intent that an error from its upstream Promise does not equate to an error in the context of `.all`

Comment: @apsillers et.al - Please see the Userland Implementations section of this TC39 Proposal for `allSettled`. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled

Comment: @RandyCasburn Ah, I see your point -- surely `allSettled` is indeed best semantics. `:)` There surely are cases where it is semantically appropriate that errors in some specific Promise(s) should *not* short-circuit resolve `.all`, but `.allSettled` ensures that all involved Promises are handled in this way, so if that's your intent, it's the best tool. I concede that you're right it is a code smell, i.e., something that may be done legitimately but is likely is an imperfect attempt to express something else.

Comment: @apsillers not even that. Using the `.catch` version below it will behave *exactly* like the `allSettled` one (the proposal actually shows that).

Comment: @JonasWilms Right, I said "there surely are cases..." for a case where one Promise involved in a `.all` should have its exceptions short-circuit `.all` while another Promise in the same `.all` collection should *not* have its exception cause a short-circuit. (I'm just pedantically clarifying my even earlier point in light of the new information of `.allSettled`. I think the utility of my point is vanishingly small, anyway. `:)`)

Comment: @apsillers ah okay, now I get your point ...

Answer (score 1):

Just return the catched Promise, so that the rejection does not bubble up to `Promise.all` (then it won't exit):

```
 return promise.catch((err) => {
   console.error("there was a problem with "+cat+" but processing should continue as normal for the other cats and dogs");
    return /*some flag that indicates that this one did throw */;
 });
```

In the future, there will be [Promise.allSettled](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled/blob/master/README.md) to solve that exact case.

Comment: can you expand on 'some flag...'? Your answer is a return with no args. To clarify, I have no interest in whether each cat was successful or not, only in that all cats have been processed.

Comment: @pinoyyid that depends on your usecase. Maybe `null` ? maybe a `Symbol()` ? It depends on the way you want to handle the error.

Comment: I don't want to handle the error at all. My catch code within `doOneCat(cat)` has already done everything that needs to be done.

Comment: @pinoyyid If you don't use the array of results from `Promise.all(...).then(...)`, then you don't care about the return value at all, and you can omit `return` entirely. If you do use the result of `.all`, then `return` whatever you wish to see in that array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are the available options:-

1. The answer from Jonas. I tried to implement this, but without success. This may be to my faulty implementation, since my `doOneCat()` is several layers of nested methods and a nested Promise.
2. Use a library such as those in https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled linked by Randy.
3. Refactor to avoid reject/catch altogether as advocated in https://blog.logrocket.com/elegant-error-handling-with-the-javascript-either-monad-76c7ae4924a1 and others.

I eventually went with option 3. I refactored my low level code to resolve with a response object containing a success/fail flag, and my higher level code tests the flag to perform the appropriate success/fail processing. This way my `Promise.all` only ever sees successfully resolved Promises. imho, this refactoring results in more readable code than the rej/catch code I had before.