# Async/await not working AWS lambda, skipping everything after await

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I'm trying to use AWS lambda to test a few API calls using `axios`, however I'm having some trouble. Every post I came across said the best way to handle promises in Lambda was to use `async/await` rather than `.then`, so I made the switch. When I run the program using `node` it works perfectly, but when I invoke the Lambda locally, it seems like everything after the `axios` call is being skipped. When I invoke the Lambda locally without `await`, the calls after it run fine, but then I'm forced to use `.then` which the Lambda doesn't wait for anyway. I've increased the Lambda timeout to `900`, and I've run `sam build` before `sam invoke local` every time.

```
function checkServers() {
    console.log("Inside checkServer");
    console.log("Before apis to test");

    // apisToTest has length of 2
    apisToTest.forEach(async (apiToTest) => {
        console.log("Api to test");
        let res = await axios(apiToTest)
        console.log("x"); // This gets skipped
        console.log(res); // This gets skipped
    })
    console.log("After api to test")
}

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log("Inside lambda handler");
    checkServers();
    console.log("After lambda handler");
};

// Used to test app using node command
checkServers()
```

This yields the following output:

```
INFO    Inside lambda handler     
INFO    Inside checkServer        
INFO    Before apis to test       
INFO    Api to test
INFO    Api to test
INFO    After api to test
INFO    After lambda handler
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/4388775 use rather a `for ... of` loop instead.

Comment: Right, `forEach` doesn’t await async functions, and nothing else in your code is either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I gave this a shot, I changed the `forEach` to a `for ... of` and made `checkServer` `async`, but it didn't resolve the issue unfortunately, the values after the `await` line still seem to get skipped. Even if `forEach` doesn't await async functions, that shouldn't prevent "x" or `res` (even if it's `undefined`) from printing, right?

Comment: How about try-catching to see if exceptions are just not thrown there?

Comment: `let res = await axios(apiToTest) ` probably throws an exception. As you are not catching it, code execution is aborted .

Comment: and why do you think aws lamda won't await a `.then()`? You just have to return a promise from your handler. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: You were right, `axios` was throwing an error, and I was hoping there was a simpler solution that I hadn't considered than working with `Promise`, thanks for your help!

Comment: Async/await does not work with `forEach` (they also don't work with `map` or `filter` or `reduce` or `find` etc). Change it to `for (let i=0; i< apisToTest.length; i++) ...`

Comment: Note that the `console.log("After API test")` happens before the API test. Like I said, `forEach` does not wait for the async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of your replies, unfortunately those weren't the ideal solutions for my use case, though they were very helpful in me coming up with the solution.

```
async function checkServers() {
    let emailBody = "";
    let callResult = "";
    let completedCalls = 0;
    let promises = [];
    for (const apiToTest of apisToTest) {
        await axios(apiToTest).then((res) => {
            // Do something
        }).catch((r) => {
            // Handle error
        })
    }
}

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;
    await checkServers();
};
```

To summarize, I replaced the `forEach` call to a `for...of` call, changed the `checkServers` to `async`, and combined `await` with `.then()` and `.catch` to handle the `Promise` result. I was unaware that both can be used to do so in tandem. Hope this helps anyone that had an issue similar to the one I had.

Comment: One small suggestion, its a common problem but there looks to be a mixture of the async/await style and the .then()
style. Consider:
```for (const apiToTest of apisToTest) {
  axios(apiToTest).then((res) => {
    // Do something
  }).catch((r) => {
    // Handle error
  })
}```
or
```try {
  for (const apiToTest of apisToTest) {
    const result = await axios(apiToTest);
  }
} catch(err) {
  // Handle error
}```

Answer (score 0):

you got two options:

1. set `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to true - and then AWS will wait until the eventloop is empty
2. await your promises. Note that you didn't await your promises on `checkServers`. Consider using `await Promise.all([...])` to wait for all your promises to finish.

Note: If you will run the lambda again, the events from the previous invocations may "leak" to the next invocation.
You can learn about it here: https://lumigo.io/blog/node-js-lambda-execution-leaks-a-practical-guide/

Disclosure: I work in the company that published this blog post

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had attempted using `await Promise.all()`, however the challenge I ran into was that if one API call failed, then the entire result would throw an error. I want to handle individual errors, as I am expecting those to come up, and I wasn't able to find a way to do that with `Promise.all()`

Comment: There are many very elegant ways to handle separate errors. Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362733/handling-errors-in-promise-all

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what saart is saying you could try the below code and see if it works:

```js
async function checkServers() {

  const promises = apisToTest.map((apiToTest) => axios(apiToTest))

  const resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(promises);

  return resolvedPromises;
}

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
      const result = await checkServers();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    
};

// Used to test app using node command
checkServers();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The challenge with `Promise.all()` was that it would error if one of the `Promises` errored. I'm expecting API calls to fail from time to time and don't want the entire `Promise` to fail, rather keep track of what passed and what failed and keep track of those.

Comment: Hi @Sal, no problem :) I have updated the code to not make the lambda handler fail. I did this by wrapping it in a try ... catch statement, so when an error is thrown it will just be logged without failing. You can learn more about try catch statements and how they work with promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function