# Why is not this promise catch fired in my promises array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I learn React JavaScript and have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-new-content-with-useeffect-z59w6?file=/src/MUITable.jsx:2854-3223) where I don't understand why the error is not shown

Here in the `watchProgress` the `catch` is not fired but it's fired in the promise so I do something wrong

```
function watchProgress(promArray) {
    let progress = 0;
    promArray.forEach(p => {
        p.then(result => {
            progress += 1;
            const percentCorrect = (progress / promArray.length) * 100;
            const math = Math.floor(percentCorrect);
            setProgressValue(math);
            console.log(`name ${result.name}`);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(`err ${err}`);
        });
    });
}
```

1. Select a file with the file picker
2. Watch the log for `err`
3. The log show  the `error` inside the promise but not `err` when I loop through all

### Update

I try something like this but I get TypeError: p.then is not a function

```
Promise.all(promArray)
    .then(arr => {
        arr.forEach(p => {
            p.then(result => {
                progress += 1;
                const percentCorrect = (progress / promArray.length) * 100;
                const math = Math.floor(percentCorrect);
                // console.log(`setProgressValue ${math}`);
                // console.log(`count ${progress}`);
                setProgressValue(math);
                console.log(`name ${result.name}`);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(`err ${err}`);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`err ${err}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using forEach you should use `Promise.all` and after the promises are resolved then you can through loop it.

```
let progress = 0;
Promise.all(promArray).then((promArray) => {
  promArray.forEach(p => {
    progress += 1;
    const percentCorrect = (progress / promArray.length) * 100;
    const math = Math.floor(percentCorrect);
    setProgressValue(math);
  })
}).catch(err => {
        console.log(`err ${err}`);
   });
```

Comment: Thanks but I need also to do the progressbar setProgressValue(math); and also handle catch error that's why `forEach`

Comment: you cant do it with foreach because its async and will result in unwanted behaviour.

Comment: nice I did not know that, but `err` is not fired how can I catch that

Comment: I update me question with some test code but I get TypeError: p.then is not a function

Comment: its because the promises has been resolved and it has returned the array of responses...now you can't do .then() to that....you just need to use that response.

Comment: This answer does not answer the OP

Comment: @saksh73 but how can I catch error if I cant use `.then` or `.catch`

Comment: @Kid - You can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362733/handling-errors-in-promise-all

Comment: @saksh73 Thanks I read it and the ` Promise.all` that he use cant individually give error message on lets say 10 promises in a promArray it will resolve all ok or give one error for all. I load files like jpg images and show them in a table row, I need to know if individual files have failed some test

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `forEach`, you should use `reduce`.

You can read this article: https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/